# What is the difference between prefix/postfix notations and map?

Tags: functions, syntax

I am new to *Mathematica* and just experimenting with the different programming constructs. I have been looking at `Map` and how to evaluate a function for a list of values and there seems to quite a number of different ways of doing this. I have used `Trace` to look at what goes on in more detail but is there any difference in the approaches shown below other than syntax? In my example, both `@` and `/@` appear to be equivalent to `Map`.

```
f[x_] := x^2;    
f /@ {1, 2, 3} // Trace
```

> {f /@ {1, 2, 3}, {f[1], f[2], f[3]}, {f[1], 1^2, 1}, {f[2], 2^2, 4}, {f[3], 3^2, 9}, {1, 4, 9}}

```
f @ {1, 2, 3} // Trace
```

> {f[{1, 2, 3}], {1, 2, 3}^2, {1^2, 2^2, 3^2}, {1^2, 1}, {2^2, 4}, {3^2, 9}, {1, 4, 9}}

```
f[{1, 2, 3}] // Trace
```

> {f[{1, 2, 3}], {1, 2, 3}^2, {1^2, 2^2, 3^2}, {1^2, 1}, {2^2, 4}, {3^2, 9}, {1, 4, 9}}

```
{1, 2, 3} // f // Trace
```

> {f[{1, 2, 3}], {1, 2, 3}^2, {1^2, 2^2, 3^2}, {1^2, 1}, {2^2, 4}, {3^2, 9}, {1, 4, 9}}

Comment: If you test with `f[x_]:=g[x]` instead you'll see a difference. The three last examples are just different notations for the same thing. `f@x` is `f[a]` is `a//f`, in `FullForm` they are all represented as `f[a]`

Comment: They are not equivalent, but `Power` has attribute `Listable` which automatically threads over lists...

Comment: ok. Thanks. I can see differences when i used the example f[x_]:=g[x]. If i use SetAttributes/ClearAttributes i can make f Listable. Very interesting that you can set attributes to control function evaluation.

Answer (score 9):

It seems to me that your tracing gives the answer to your question. The output of the last three traces show identical evaluation and, indeed, this is true in general -- `@` is the prefix form of `[]` and `//` is the postfix form.

The first trace, the one using `/@` (which is just the infix form of `Map`) yields the same result as the other three, but arrives at it differently, so there is a real difference between `Map` and function calls. `Map` gives the same result in your examples because `Power` (^) has the [`Listable`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Listable.html) attribute, which means it automatically maps across lists. But in general, you can't expect a function passed a list to give the same result as when it is mapped across a list, because `Listable` is not an attribute of most functions. However, it *is* an attribute of all built-in functions that also have the [`NumericFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/NumericFunction.html) attribute.

#### Edit

I implied above that, in general, there is no difference among `@`, `[]` and `//`. That is not quite accurate because these operators do differ in precedence.

The operators `[ ]` and `@` have very high precedence, so it's hard find an example where precedence matters. However, `++` is one the few operators that has precedence lower than `[ ]` but higher than `@`. With `++` an example can be contrived.

```
f[1] = 1; ++f[1]
```

> 2

```
f[1] = 1; ++f@1
```

> PreIncrement::rvalue: f is not a variable with a value, so its value cannot be changed. >>
>
> ```
> (++f)[1]
> ```

```
f[1] = 1; ++(f@1)
```

> 2

On the other hand, `//` has a rather low precedence, so it easy to get an unexpected results with the `//` operator.

```
x -> y[z]
```

> x -> y[z]

```
x -> y@z
```

> x -> y[z]

```
x -> z // y
```

> y[x -> z]

```
x -> (z // y)
```

> x -> y[z]

Comment: You could probably also add a note on the difference in precedence between `@`, `[]` and `//`, since a new user is quite likely to not know that and trip up.

Comment: @rm-rf. I think you changed the scope of the question with your recent edit. I'll work on an update to my answer that addresses the additional issue you introduced. I can't do it immediately because I find I need to refresh my understanding of precedence between @, [ ] and //

Comment: I didn't change the scope; I only gave it a title that reflected what the OP described in the question and the examples (or what I understood it to be). It so happened that the OP's confusion was because of the Listable property. No rush on the update :)

Comment: Another common and important precedence difference appears with `Part`: `a@b[[c]]` vs `a[b][[c]]`