# when is f@g not the same as f[g]?

Tags: programming, operators, function-comparison, precedence

I have always thought that `f@g` will give the same result as `f[g]` in all cases, and it is just a matter of style which one to use and that `g` will always evaluates first, and then `f` will evaluate using the result of `g` evaluation. I never thought that there can be any precedence issue here, since no one ever mentioned it in all the times I have been using Mathematica.

So I was really surprised when I found one case where this was not so. So my question is: How does one know when `f@g` is not the same as `f[g]` ?

The help says nothing about this (thanks to chat room for giving me the link to this, I searched and could not find it)

http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Prefix.html

Even though one can see the word `precedence` and `grouping` but no explanation of where these are talked about and no more links to follow

`Prefix[expr, h, precedence, grouping] can be used to specify how the output form should be parenthesized.`

clearly this is a precedence issue. But I have never seen this mentioned before any where.

```
Tr[Times @@@ {{2, 3}, {4, 5}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Tr @ Times @@@ {{2, 3}, {4, 5}}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Tr @ ( Times @@@ {{2, 3}, {4, 5}} )
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

What seems to have happened is that in `Tr@Times@@@....`  the command `Tr` grabbed `Times` before `Times` was applied. You can replaced `Tr` by `Total` also and see the same effect.

ps. This is another reason for me to not use `@` too much. I I really never liked to use `@` and always liked the good old fashioned `[]` as it seems clearer also, and now safer also.

**question is**: What is the rule(s) of thumb to use? One should always look ahead and check before using `@` to make sure precedence is met? Any other cases than this one might have to watch out for? If there are very few cases, may be one can add them to their cheat sheet. Where are the `precedence` of all operators listed so one can check?

Comment: you might want to look at @m_goldbergs answer here: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/19219/what-is-the-difference-between-prefix-postfix-notations-and-map/19222#19222

Comment: there are some hints in the following tutorials in the Mathematica Documentation Center: tutorial/OperatorInputForms; tutorial/SpecialWaysToInputExpressions; tutorial/DefiningOutputFormats

Comment: One issue is that `Precedence` cannot be easily found in the documentation.

Comment: Related: How to introduce [Prefix operator with low precedence](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6338/89) to avoid unwanted binding toward the left.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

### Operator Precedence Table

Unless one wishes to write in `FullForm` a competent *Mathematica* user must be familiar with at least the majority of syntax precedence rules, which are described in the [Operator Precedence](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/OperatorInputForms.html) table.

*Clarification:* I do not mean that one must memorize (most of) this entire table be competent, but rather that one should know it well enough not to be surprised most of the time.  Since memorizing the complete table is impractical (for me at least) I recommend having [analysis tools](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/3146/121) at the ready when writing or reading code.

Here is an excerpt from that table:

[image]

It can be seen that `expr1 @@@ expr2` is well below `expr1 @ expr2` on the table which means that `@` has greater *binding power* than `@@@`.  In other words:

- `f @ g @@@ h` is interpreted as `(f @ g) @@@ h` not `f @ (g @@@ h)`

You can see that there are a number of forms between `expr1[expr2]` and `expr1 @ expr2` -- these are the cases where the two will behave differently in a potentially unanticipated way.  For example:

- `Part`: `f @ g [[1]]` is interpreted as `f[ g[[1]] ]` not `f[g][[1]]`
- `Increment`: `f @ g ++` is interpreted as `f[g++]` not `f[g]++`
- `PreIncrement`: `f @ ++ g` is valid input: `f[++g]`

Of course the relatively high binding power of `@` (see the rest of the table) means that many such things as `f @ g + h` are interpreted `f[g] + h` rather than `f[g + h]`.  *Most* operators and input forms have lower binding power than `@` so this behavior should be evident with minimal experimentation.

In addition to these the excerpt includes a couple of other interesting forms.  The first is `PatternTest` which is unusual for having greater binding power than application brackets, therefore:

- `f?g[h]` is interpreted as `(f?g)[h]` not `f?(g[h])`

The second is infix notation `a ~f~ b` (which many people know I am found of).  This has lower binding power than `@`, and it is left-associative which means:

- `p @ q ~f~ i @ j ~g~ x @ y` is interpreted as `g[f[p[q], i[j]], x[y]]`

---

### `Precedence` function

There is an undocumented function `Precedence` that when applied a Symbol gives the precedence of the corresponding operator, if one exists.  Here is my effort to match its output to the order declared in the table above:

```
{#, Precedence@#} & /@
 {PatternTest, default, Part, Increment, Decrement, PreIncrement, 
   PreDecrement, Prefix, InvisibleApplication, Infix, Map, MapAll, Apply} // TableForm
```

$\begin{array}{ll}
 \text{PatternTest} & 680. \\
 \text{default} & 670. \\
 \text{Part} & 670. \\
 \text{Increment} & 660. \\
 \text{Decrement} & 660. \\
 \text{PreIncrement} & 660. \\
 \text{PreDecrement} & 660. \\
 \text{Prefix} & 640. \\
 \text{InvisibleApplication} & 640. \\
 \text{Infix} & 630. \\
 \text{Map} & 620. \\
 \text{MapAll} & 620. \\
 \text{Apply} & 620.
\end{array}$

I don't know if there is a Symbol that corresponds to `expr1[expr2]` but since the default precedence value (illustrated arbitrarily by `default`) matches its location in the table I don't think it matters.

Comment: That table is a complete answer but do you think my interpretation is correct?

Comment: @Kuba Since `Precedence` is undocumented I am uncertain of your application and its authority; I prefer to reference the table instead.

Comment: @LeoFang It would be better familiarize yourself with the syntax table so that each case can be handled most efficiently however there is nothing wrong with using extra parentheses.  I [personally](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/13128/121) find that limiting the use of parentheses enhances readability of my own code as I know that they are usually there for a purpose.  You can also use the application bracket form rather than parentheses e.g. `Map[f, # + 2 & @ g]` instead of `(f) /@ (# + 2 & @ g)`.

Comment: Mr.Wizard I largely agree, but I think still a lot can be learned from `Precedence`. Just to realize that prefix, infix and postfix notations are all governed by comparing their precedence-numbers is great, I think. Especially that the number for a postfix notation can be compared with that of a prefix one. So you can have all notations in a row in your mind and induce "relative precedences" by transitivity. The `Precedence` function can then help to get good examples, like your `f@g++`, which makes you realize ++ has higher precedence than @. (and therefore higher than // etc)

Comment: @JacobAkkerboom You should take all your comments and put them into an answer :)

Comment: Practically any link to that table gets a +1 from me. Now to determine if this is one of those rare cases where I wouldn't give it. =D (Yes, sarcasm.)

Comment: @rcollyer Oh good; for a minute there I thought I was going to have to *earn* your vote. :^)

Answer (score 18):

If you are looking for **complete answer**, take a look at Mr. Wizard's :)

Also, see the **comments of @JacobAkkerboom** below, who proved I was too hasty. :)

I was **right** that the function OP is asking about at the end is `Precedence` but I was **wrong** in my interpretation of what is happening.

I will leave this for future visitors as it is not so obvious.

Also, everyone that upvoted, feel free to un-upvote if you wish :)

### right part:

---

Precedence of functions is given by `Precedence` :)

More here:  [What are some useful, undocumented Mathematica functions?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/819/5478)

"Good old fashioned" `[]` is safer but I really like `@`, I just have to remeber what is going to happen basing on my experiece, because no one will remember all precedences :)

In fact, sometimes I like to do `f @ ( some code )`. The more different brackets, the more transparent code is, IMO.

---

### wrong part

```
Precedence[Apply]
Precedence[Compose]
```

> ```
> 620
> 670
> ```

**So that's why** `Tr[Times]` is done before `Times` is applied to the list.

What is also an answer to your question about precedences of functions. It is `Precedence`, an undocumented function.

There is a discussion about what `@` is. In my opinion `f @ g` does not mean that there's operation `Prefix` with `f` on `g`. `Prefix` is only a syntax form(?). What is happening is:

```
Compose[f, g]
```

That's why I've checked `Precedence` of `Compose`.

More about `Compose`: [Why there is no name...](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/28778/why-there-is-no-name-for-12) (*this link is true itself :P*)

---

As you see the wrong part is longer...

Comment: Nice find! I never knew about this function

Comment: @Nasser That's why we all should go back to main Q&A often :) [What are some useful..](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/819/5478)

Comment: I spend more than one hr searching on this before, and also asked on chat. I could not even find help on @ since Mathematica ?@ gives nothing. It is very frustrating why one can't find help on @ when it is one of the most used symbols around. I had no idea it is called `Prefix` and did not even know there was a precedence function.

Comment: No, @ is called prefix. I did not know this. Michale from chat helped me with this.

Comment: @Nasser Prefix is only a way of diplay things, what is happening it is `Compose[f, arg]`. But still, I can be wrong.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries Ok, but I admit I'm not 100% sure if I'm right, maybe it is a coincidence since `Composition` has the same `Precedence` as `Compose` :)

Comment: @Nasser about documentation, it is really great on the beginning. Later, when one is starting asking deeper question it can be really annoying to find the answers one is looking for. :/

Comment: @Nasser That is also why this site is so great and popular :)

Comment: @Kuba I think it is not about `Compose`, but about `Prefix`. Note that `Compose` has precedence 670, which is the default value. Usually this indicates that the function in question has no shorthand notation. Also see `Precedence[Postfix]`. That one is very low, consistent with // .

Comment: I might not think properly since it's late midnight here, but is this answer related to `Precedence` also able to explain why sometimes one gets different results by using a) `f[(some stuff)]` and b) `f[x]/.x->(some stuff)`? I may not be making sense now...perhaps I better work out an minimal example and post a new question tomorrow morning.

Comment: @JacobAkkerboom I'm not sure if I understand you :) This is about `Prefix` but also about `Compose`, imo. I think `Precedence` of `Compose` is the answer, but there would not be any question without `Prefix` notation. I'm still expressing my opinion rather than facts :)

Comment: Kuba, actually the example by Mr.Wizard shows why it is about Prefix. `f@g++` gets parsed to `f[g++]`. This is because @ has lower precedence than `Increment`. We can see that indeed `Precedence[Increment]==660`. So if the precedence of @ was really 670, it would have been parsed as `Increment[f[g]]`. Note that you can never get Mathematica to show you an expression with @ in it in output. It is really a matter of parsing, Mathematica forgets how the expression was entered. I think no function like `Compose` is used as it would feel strange to me to use such a function in parsing code.

Comment: Compare also `Hold[f@g ..]` and
`Hold[f@g++]`. I think you cannot explain the difference if you think the precedence of @ should be 670 :)

Comment: @JacobAkkerboom omg, I'm wrong :) I have to delete this or reformulate :?

Comment: @Kuba just reformulate, it is a good answer I think :). You point to the right functions :)

Comment: @JacobAkkerboom Thanks for saving my *** :) Do you agree with the content now?

Comment: Hehe no problem :). I agree with the content. Maybe you could try to show using examples that it is really about Prefix and not Compose? Take anything from the comments you wish, I will delete my comments if you absorb them :).

Comment: @JacobAkkerboom don't delete them, make an answer :)

Comment: @Kuba in version 9.0.0 entering @ in the documentation center will point to `Prefix`. But really @ is no shorthand notation for any function. It kind of makes sense to let it point to `Prefix` though. Also I don't think you can make any expression where @ stands for `Prefix`, short of using something like an `InterpretationBox`. So in this sense `Prefix` has no special notation and calling `Precedence` on it should not have a special value. All in all things kind of make sense, but yeah I guess the documentation here is not so nice :(.

Comment: @Kuba I don't know why I rant :)

Comment: @JacobAkkerboom :) Feel free to share your thoughts, I find them educational :)

Answer (score 2):

I was making a custom typesetting form (`MakeBoxes[]` et al.), and happened to notice that `Precedence[]` works on box forms.  This lets you get the precedences for things like `F[x]` or `F@x` (I actually mean `F@x`, not `Prefix@F@x` or similar).  The one shortfall I noticed is that when fed bare symbols (like in `Precedence@"F"`, where the double-quotes are actually the normal box-representation for such a thing), the precedence for a string is used, rather than the default precedence for a symbol without any built-in precedence assignment.

Anyways, here's a handy table for some of the basic "otherwise not enumerable via make a method like `Table[ Precedence@ToExpression@#, Names[...] ]`.

Code:

```
Grid[#, Frame -> Thick,
   Dividers -> {All, {All, 2 -> Thick}},
   ItemStyle -> {Automatic, {Bold}},
   Background -> {Automatic, {{LightGray, Automatic}}}
   ] &@
 Prepend[{"Prec", "Expr", "Raw"}]@
  Sort@Map[Through@*{Precedence, ToExpression, RawBoxes}]@{
     "F",
     RowBox[{"(", "F", ")"}],
     RowBox[{"F", "[", "x", "]"}],
     RowBox[{"F", "@", "x"}],
     RowBox[{"(", RowBox[{"F", "@", "x"}], ")"}],
     RowBox[{"x", "//", "F"}],
     RowBox[{RowBox[{"F", "[", "a", "]"}], "[", "x", "]"}],
     RowBox[{RowBox[{"F", "[", "a", "]"}], "@", "x"}],
     RowBox[{RowBox[{"(", RowBox[{"F", "@", "a"}], ")"}], "[", "x", 
       "]"}],
     RowBox[{RowBox[{"(", RowBox[{"F", "@", "a"}], ")"}], "@", "x"}],
     RowBox[{"F", "@", RowBox[{"G", "[", "x", "]"}]}],
     RowBox[{"F", "@", RowBox[{"(", RowBox[{"G", "@", "x"}], ")"}]}],
     RowBox[{"F", "@", RowBox[{"G", "@", "x"}]}],
     RowBox[{"F", "[", RowBox[{"x", ",", "y"}], "]"}],
     RowBox[{"x", "~", "F", "~", "y"}],
     RowBox[{"3", "x"}],
     RowBox[{"3", "+", "x"}],
     Prefix,
     Infix,
     Postfix,
     Construct,
     Times,
     Plus
     }
```

Output:

[image: Precedence Values of Box-Forms of Expressions]

If anyone wants me to clean-up-and-post a copy of e.g. `PrefixForm[...]`, let me know.  I have too many forked versions to post any single one at the moment, but I use is all the time and find that it makes digesting output mentally easier.  Like e.g. `MatrixForm`, the kernel just sees a single wrapper, but the front-end formats the output differently.  When re-evaluated as input, the wrapper goes away, via `InterpretationBox`.  Pretty simple but some of the bells-n-whistles were a bit of a pain, like coming up with an exclusion list so that e.g. `{1}` doesn't format as `List@1`, `HoldForm@F@x` does format as `F@x`, stray uses of `Prefix@F@x` still just format as `F@x`, nasty things like `Definition@F` only transform when you really want them to, held expressions aren't expanded, repeated calls to `PrefixForm` don't mess-up the output, etc.