# Compute percentages in a list

Tags: list-manipulation, data

I have a data file which contains thousands of lines and each line has eight elements. Here is a small sample of the data file

```
-4.00      -0.80   0.1886024468848907E+01   0.1467147621657460E+01   -.1217067274319363E+01   0.7206100000000000E+03   0.7693457688734395E-12    5
-4.00      -0.70   0.1430357986632780E+01   -.1404093461650013E+01   -.1742223680347601E+01   0.1824700000000000E+03   0.8439003681169850E-12    8
-4.00      -0.60   -.1324719768465547E+01   0.1740130076002850E+01   0.1497978622206873E+01   0.5479900000000000E+03   0.4264485578634903E-14    2
-4.00      -0.50   0.1358536876189560E+01   -.1580696533502541E+01   0.1621539980382560E+01   0.2881100000000000E+03   0.1319885603098060E-13    4
-4.00      -0.40   -.1588487538231399E+01   0.1275577589608218E+01   0.1707607247015512E+01   0.1337500000000000E+03   0.1057878487713421E-12    2
-4.00      -0.30   0.1755414125374284E+01   0.1332710827520201E+01   0.1477984475201826E+01   0.6426400000000000E+03   0.1459764022611444E-13    1
-4.00      -0.20   0.1245972697710741E+01   0.1540633564543885E+01   0.1777167629372046E+01   0.6112200000000000E+03   0.5718386586661092E-13    1
-4.00      -0.10   -.1311461418732105E+01   -.1594149065989313E+01   0.1661344176980193E+01   0.3507800000000000E+03   0.6765588799377521E-14    3
```

I read this file using

```
data = ReadList["data.out", Number, RecordLists -> True];
```

The total length of the list is obtained, of course as

```
ntot = Length[data];
```

The list contains eight elements per row and the last of them is an integer taking values in the interval [0,8]. What I want is the following:

(a). Count how many rows have 0 value at the last element (let's suppose there are `n0`), how many have 1, 2, 3, ... , 8. Then calculate the corresponding percentages `per0 = n0/ntot`, `per1 = n1/ntot`, etc. It could be nice if this was inside a DO loop with `i = 0,8`.

(b). Count again percentages but using more than one criteria this time. For example, count how many rows have 1 at the last element and the value of the seventh element is smaller than `10^{-4}`.

Any suggestions?

**EDIT**

Using's @Kuba's solution we have

```
{{5, 656}, {8, 640}, {2, 673}, {4, 663}, {1, 673}, {3, 663}, {6, 656}, {7, 640}, {0, 19}}
```

Is it possible to divide each sum automatically with `ntot` thus obtaining the percentages?

```
{{5, 656/ntot}, {8, 640/ntot}, {2, 673/ntot}, {4, 663/ntot}, {1, 673/ntot}, {3, 663/ntot}, {6, 656/ntot}, {7,640/ntot}, {0, 19/ntot}}
```

Also it would be great if they were sorted from 0 to 8 not randomly as they are now.

Comment: try `data[[ ;; , 8]] // Tally` there is all what you need to calculate those %.

Comment: @Kuba Not exactly what I need; see my EDIT. What about the case where two criteria are used?

Comment: The problem is the at each step you need functions that are called exactly as the procedure which you want to do (so they are easy to find). Earlier it was `Count` or `Tally`, now you are asking for `SortBy` and at the end `Cases` or `Select`. And this is a problem because it shows no research effort :/

Comment: @Kuba Not at all, I 'm just unfamiliar with list manipulation. Perhaps you should post a complete answer showing these functions so I can accept it.

Comment: @Kuba `SortBy[data[[;; , 8]] // Tally, 1]` done! Now, what is left is how to insert `ntot` inside computing the percentage and the case where more than two criteria apply.

Comment: I'm sure that you can handle this and post an answer. Also remember that `Divide` is `Listable` so you can just `SortBy[data[[;; , 8]] // Tally, 1][[;;, 2]] / ntot`. For extended criteria use `Cases` or `Select`.

Comment: @Kuba As I said, I am not familiar with functions like `Cases` and `Select` so reading the corresponding documentation was not very helpful since my case is rather complicated. SO, I think the best approach is to see how it could be done. How hard is to post an answer? After all, I have to accept it since you know the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to acheive this:

```
SetDirectory@NotebookDirectory[];
data = Import["list.txt", "Table"] (*I saved your sample in txt file*)

ntot = Length@data;

temp = SortBy[Tally@data[[;; , -1]], 1];
temp[[;; , 2]] = temp[[;; , 2]] 100/ntot // N; 
(*I've multiplied by 100 to get % value not the ratio*)
temp
```

> ```
> {{1, 25.}, {2, 25.}, {3, 12.5}, {4, 12.5}, {5, 12.5}, {8, 12.5}}
> ```

What can be useful, but the difference is it will "count" also what is not there (e.g `7`):

```
viahist = HistogramList[data[[;; , 8]], {1}, "Probability"]
```

> ```
> {{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9},
>   {0., 0.25, 0.25, 0.125, 0.125, 0.125, 0., 0., 0.125}}
> ```

notice that first part is a list of intervals limits so at the end:

```
{Most@#, #2 100} & @@ viahist // Transpose
```

> ```
> {{0, 0.}, {1, 25.}, {2, 25.}, {3, 12.5}, {4, 12.5}, {5, 12.5}, 
> {6, 0.}, {7, 0.}, {8, 12.5}}
> ```

---

For your second question, one way to do this is:

```
Length@Select[data, #[[7]] < 10^(-13) && #[[8]] == 2 &] 100 / ntot // N
```

> ```
> 12.5
> ```

---

Comment: @Vaggelis_Z but please, do not accept, this question is so broad that, unless it's closed, it can provide many interesting answers. I hope it will help you.

Comment: Everything is great! But I cannot understand why you don't want to accept your answer? A minor question: is there any difference between `Lenght@data` and `Length[data]`? I mean is it more fast? I always use the standard `[ ]` notation.

Comment: @Vaggelis_Z Because better do not discourage others :) it is good habbit to wait with an accept. About `@`, take a look [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/30425/5478). In this case it does not matter.

Answer (score 1):

You could write functions to generalize this but for your specific problem:

```
data = Import["list.txt", "Data"];
ntot = Length[data];
```

(a) to get percentages of elements in the last column (you could optionally `Sort` this list too)

```
Inner[Times, Tally[data[[All, -1]]], {1, 100./ntot}, List]
```

Note that I used `Inner` here but normally I use `Part` for this sort of thing but Kuba did something similar:

```
tmp = Tally[data[[All, -1]]];
tmp[[All, 2]] = tmp[[All, 2]]*100./ntot;
```

(b) to get percentage when last column is 1 and a condition is applied on the second last column

```
Length[Cases[data, {__, z_ /; z < 10^-4, 1}]]*100./ntot
```