# Extracting lists from list based on length

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list looking like this;

```
{{"ADS GY Equity", "", "", "ALV GY Equity", "", "", "BAS GY Equity", 
"", "", "BAYN GY Equity", "", "", "BEI GY Equity", "", "", 
"BMW GY Equity", ""}, {"Date", "PX_LAST", "", "Date", "PX_LAST", "",
"Date", "PX_LAST", "", "Date", "PX_LAST", "", "Date", "PX_LAST", 
"", "Date", "PX_LAST"}, {"addidas", 17.925, "", "alvac", 287.292, 
"", "basse", 24.875, "", "bayern", 42.34, "", "begge", 23.667, "", 
"BMW", 29.49}, {{2000, 1, 4, 0, 0, 0.}, 17.5, 
"", {2000, 1, 4, 0, 0, 0.}, 285.934, "", {2000, 1, 4, 0, 0, 0.}, 
23.925, "", {2000, 1, 4, 0, 0, 0.}, 41.216, 
"", {2000, 1, 4, 0, 0, 0.}, 21.333, "", {2000, 1, 4, 0, 0, 0.}, 
28.3}, {{2000, 1, 5, 0, 0, 0.}, 17.5, "", {2000, 1, 5, 0, 0, 0.}, 
294.078, "", {2000, 1, 5, 0, 0, 0.}, 23.375, 
"", {2000, 1, 5, 0, 0, 0.}, 40.176, "", {2000, 1, 5, 0, 0, 0.}, 21.,
 "", {2000, 1, 5, 0, 0, 0.}, 27.74}, {{2000, 1, 6, 0, 0, 0.}, 18.25,
 "", {2000, 1, 6, 0, 0, 0.}, 297.698, "", {2000, 1, 6, 0, 0, 0.}, 
24.015, "", {2000, 1, 6, 0, 0, 0.}, 41.356, 
"", {2000, 1, 6, 0, 0, 0.}, 21.867, "", {2000, 1, 6, 0, 0, 0.}, 
27.65}, {{2000, 1, 7, 0, 0, 0.}, 18., "", {2000, 1, 7, 0, 0, 0.}, 
305.977, "", {2000, 1, 7, 0, 0, 0.}, 25., 
"", {2000, 1, 7, 0, 0, 0.}, 43.08, "", {2000, 1, 7, 0, 0, 0.}, 
22.33, "", {2000, 1, 7, 0, 0, 0.}, 27.6}, {{2000, 1, 10, 0, 0, 0.}, 
18.272, "", {2000, 1, 10, 0, 0, 0.}, 307.742, 
"", {2000, 1, 10, 0, 0, 0.}, 25.11, "", {2000, 1, 10, 0, 0, 0.}, 
44.644, "", {2000, 1, 10, 0, 0, 0.}, 22.667, 
"", {2000, 1, 10, 0, 0, 0.}, 28.7}, {{2000, 1, 11, 0, 0, 0.}, 
18.103, "", "", "", "", {2000, 1, 11, 0, 0, 0.}, 23.995, 
"", {2000, 1, 11, 0, 0, 0.}, 43.323, "", {2000, 1, 11, 0, 0, 0.}, 
21.883, "", {2000, 1, 11, 0, 0, 0.}, 
28.6}, {{2000, 1, 12, 0, 0, 0.}, 18., "", "", "", 
"", {2000, 1, 12, 0, 0, 0.}, 24., "", {2000, 1, 12, 0, 0, 0.}, 
41.45, "", {2000, 1, 12, 0, 0, 0.}, 21.717, 
"", {2000, 1, 12, 0, 0, 0.}, 28.19}, {{2000, 1, 13, 0, 0, 0.}, 
17.462, "", "", "", "", {2000, 1, 13, 0, 0, 0.}, 23.75, 
"", {2000, 1, 13, 0, 0, 0.}, 41.169, "", {2000, 1, 13, 0, 0, 0.}, 
22.163, "", {2000, 1, 13, 0, 0, 0.}, 
27.4}, {{2000, 1, 14, 0, 0, 0.}, 16.837, "", "", "", 
"", {2000, 1, 14, 0, 0, 0.}, 23.75, "", {2000, 1, 14, 0, 0, 0.}, 
42.152, "", {2000, 1, 14, 0, 0, 0.}, 22.583, 
"", {2000, 1, 14, 0, 0, 0.}, 27.2}, {{2000, 1, 17, 0, 0, 0.}, 17., 
"", "", "", "", {2000, 1, 17, 0, 0, 0.}, 23.935, "", "", "", 
"", {2000, 1, 17, 0, 0, 0.}, 23.33, "", {2000, 1, 17, 0, 0, 0.}, 
27.28}, {{2000, 1, 18, 0, 0, 0.}, 17., "", "", "", 
"", {2000, 1, 18, 0, 0, 0.}, 23.975, "", "", "", 
"", {2000, 1, 18, 0, 0, 0.}, 22.667, "", {2000, 1, 18, 0, 0, 0.}, 
27.}, {{2000, 1, 19, 0, 0, 0.}, 16.65, "", "", "", 
"", {2000, 1, 19, 0, 0, 0.}, 24.92, "", "", "", 
"", {2000, 1, 19, 0, 0, 0.}, 23.3, "", {2000, 1, 19, 0, 0, 0.}, 
27.59}}
```

I want to extract every list which has length 14 or 15. This should leave me with eight lists, because I also want to drop the lists/columns with no values in it.

This is how the output should look like after extraction

```
  {{{"ADS GY Equity", "", "BAS GY Equity", "", "BEI GY Equity", "", 
 "BMW GY Equity", ""}, {"Date", "PX_LAST", "Date", "PX_LAST", 
 "Date", "PX_LAST", "Date", "PX_LAST"}, {"addidas", 17.925, "basse",
  24.875, "begge", 23.667, "BMW", 29.49}, {{2000, 1, 4, 0, 0, 0.}, 
 17.5, {2000, 1, 4, 0, 0, 0.}, 23.925, {2000, 1, 4, 0, 0, 0.}, 
 21.333, {2000, 1, 4, 0, 0, 0.}, 28.3}, {{2000, 1, 5, 0, 0, 0.}, 
 17.5, {2000, 1, 5, 0, 0, 0.}, 23.375, {2000, 1, 5, 0, 0, 0.}, 
 21., {2000, 1, 5, 0, 0, 0.}, 27.74}, {{2000, 1, 6, 0, 0, 0.}, 
 18.25, {2000, 1, 6, 0, 0, 0.}, 24.015, {2000, 1, 6, 0, 0, 0.}, 
 21.867, {2000, 1, 6, 0, 0, 0.}, 27.65}, {{2000, 1, 7, 0, 0, 0.}, 
  18., {2000, 1, 7, 0, 0, 0.}, 25., {2000, 1, 7, 0, 0, 0.}, 
 22.33, {2000, 1, 7, 0, 0, 0.}, 27.6}, {{2000, 1, 10, 0, 0, 0.}, 
 18.272, {2000, 1, 10, 0, 0, 0.}, 25.11, {2000, 1, 10, 0, 0, 0.}, 
 22.667, {2000, 1, 10, 0, 0, 0.}, 28.7}, {{2000, 1, 11, 0, 0, 0.}, 
 18.103, {2000, 1, 11, 0, 0, 0.}, 23.995, {2000, 1, 11, 0, 0, 0.}, 
 21.883, {2000, 1, 11, 0, 0, 0.}, 28.6}, {{2000, 1, 12, 0, 0, 0.}, 
 18., {2000, 1, 12, 0, 0, 0.}, 24., {2000, 1, 12, 0, 0, 0.}, 
 21.717, {2000, 1, 12, 0, 0, 0.}, 28.19}, {{2000, 1, 13, 0, 0, 0.}, 
 17.462, {2000, 1, 13, 0, 0, 0.}, 23.75, {2000, 1, 13, 0, 0, 0.}, 
 22.163, {2000, 1, 13, 0, 0, 0.}, 27.4}, {{2000, 1, 14, 0, 0, 0.}, 
 16.837, {2000, 1, 14, 0, 0, 0.}, 23.75, {2000, 1, 14, 0, 0, 0.}, 
 22.583, {2000, 1, 14, 0, 0, 0.}, 27.2}, {{2000, 1, 17, 0, 0, 0.}, 
 17., {2000, 1, 17, 0, 0, 0.}, 23.935, {2000, 1, 17, 0, 0, 0.}, 
 23.33, {2000, 1, 17, 0, 0, 0.}, 27.28}, {{2000, 1, 18, 0, 0, 0.}, 
 17., {2000, 1, 18, 0, 0, 0.}, 23.975, {2000, 1, 18, 0, 0, 0.}, 
 22.667, {2000, 1, 18, 0, 0, 0.}, 27.}, {{2000, 1, 19, 0, 0, 0.}, 
 16.65, {2000, 1, 19, 0, 0, 0.}, 24.92, {2000, 1, 19, 0, 0, 0.}, 
 23.3, {2000, 1, 19, 0, 0, 0.}, 27.59}}}
```

If I where to explain simply what has been done, It only extracted the companies date and closing price where the number of closing prices was equal to the number of longest number of closing prices for any of the companies.

Comment: If I delete all fields with value `""` none of the lists are length 14 or 15.  With your data as `dat` `Length /@ DeleteCases[dat, "", {2}]` yields `{6, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 10, 10, 10, 10, 8, 8, 8}`

Comment: To make it simple I want to pick out every stock, all its input. But I want to drop the empty columns as well as the stocks with dates not as late as the latest date.

Comment: This means that it should drop ALV GY Equity, its column with dates and close price, the same with BAYN GY Equity. This is because the last date in this lists is not equal to 19/01/00. In other words they do not have equal amount of rows.

Comment: The list is going to grow larger and larger, so I want a function that I can run to extract the values automatically.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I still don't understand.  Could you please give a somewhat shorter example *and* the exact output you desire?

Comment: Edited the post so you can see the exact output.

Comment: Why isn't "BMW GY Equity" included in the output?

Comment: Unbelivable, it should be included! Copy and past error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Starting with your data assigned to `dat` please try this:

```
tdat = Partition[dat\[Transpose], 2, 3];

newdat = Join @@ DeleteCases[tdat, {{__, ""}, _}]\[Transpose];
```

I am going by the assumption that any primary column ending with `""` means that it is short and should be pared from the table.

Sample:

```
newdat // MatrixForm
```

[image]

#### Explanation

As requested here is an explanation of my code.  Due to the format of tables in *Mathematica* it is usually much easier to operate on rows rather than columns therefore my first step is to [`Transpose`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Transpose.html) the data.  ([`\[Transpose]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/character/Transpose.html) is a special transpose symbol; see the linked documentation.)

When looking at the data a structure becomes apparent: there are two columns of data in each group, and a spacing or dividing column containing nothing but `""`.  (Indicentially these dividing columns are completely omitted in my output; if you need them, ask, and I'll put them back in.)  I therefore [`Partition`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Partition.html) the data into groups of two columns, moving three places between each group and thereby skipping the "empty" dividing columns.  I call this data `tdat`.

Now that the data is in a row-based form and grouped we can use fairly simple pattern matching to extract only the full-length sections.  It is simpler in this case to delete the unwanted ones so I use [`DeleteCases`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/DeleteCases.html).  My pattern is:

```
{{__, ""}, _}
```

This pattern will be matched to each group of two rows (originally columns).  It is a literal list with two elements.  The second is `_` which is short for [`Blank[]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Blank.html) and matches any single expression; I use this because I want to allow any second column.  The first element is `{__, ""}` which matches a list (here row, originally column) that starts with any series of elements (`__`, short for [`BlankSequence[]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/BlankSequence.html)) and ends with literal `""`.  We therefore match any data group the first row (column) of which ends with `""` and delete these.

Finally, the data groups are joined into a single table using [`Join`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Join.html) and @@ (short for [`Apply`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Apply.html)), then transposed back to column form.  Note that the low [precedence](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/30430/121) of the `\[Transpose]` operator means that this transpose is done *after* the `Join`.

By the way, if you are doing this on a large volume of data there will be faster methods than pattern matching, perhaps using [`Pick`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Pick.html) in place of the `DeleteCases` step.  However, I find pattern matching more versatile and concise, and therefore the best place to start unless speed or large data is a priority.

Comment: Thank you! Could you explain step by step the logic behind?

Comment: When you say paired from the table does it mean that you are dropping every row with "" in it or does it mean that you are joining them?

Comment: @ALEXANDER I am dropping them from the table.

Comment: Then its exactly how I want it.

Comment: btw \ does not work when I am writing it. It becomes a small t

Comment: When I use classroom assistance I am able to put in "\" but I get an error message when running the function.

Comment: @ALEXANDER Please see my explanation.  When you paste `\[Transpose]` into *Mathematica* it should indeed become a small capital T -- it is a special transpose operator.  If you do not like this you can use e.g. `newdat = Transpose[ Join @@ DeleteCases[tdat, {{__, ""}, _}] ];`

Comment: Could you give me the first function in this output format as well?

Comment: @ALEXANDER it would be: `tdat = Partition[Transpose[dat], 2, 3];` -- sorry for the confusion.

Comment: No its great, the more confused I get and the more I understand after the explanation, usually means that I have learned more! Not only did I learn how extract, but also what small capital T means. Thank you very much!

Comment: Do you know where I can go to see good examples for how to extract and manipulate lists?

Comment: @ALEXANDER I think this site itself has many good examples.  You can search for questions with a specific [tag](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tags) by enclosing the tag name in square brackets; here is a search for the word "extract" within the `list-manipulation` tag: [search](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=[list-manipulation]%20extract).  See also the [basic tutorial](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/ManipulatingListsOverview.html) on this topic.

Comment: I am still struggling understanding the pattern matching. If we divide; {{__, ""}, _}.. Does 
{__ - Represent column 1,
"" - Represent column 2, and 
__ - Represent column 3 and 4

Comment: @ALEXANDER In my use there is no column 3 or 4; there is only a group of two columns.  `{__, ""}` represents the first column and `_` the second.

Comment: does that mean that the last part _) --> represents group two?

Comment: @ALEXANDER Each group is separately checked against the entire pattern `{{__, ""}, _}` -- if it matches it is discarded, if it does not match it is kept.  I'm going to bed so I won't be able to answer more questions today.

Comment: Okey! That means that in some groups the pattern doesnt match, would you give an example of how one row where the pattern does not match look like. Looking forward to hear from you!

Comment: @ALEXANDER please meet me in [Chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2234/mathematica).

Comment: @ALEXANDER I guess I missed you.  I'll try again later.