# Checking whether a number can be composed from the cube of its digit

Tags: algorithm

How to check whether or not the sum of the cube of each digit of a number is equal to the number itself?

In the following code, I tried to return the number in question whenever it matches the condition.

```
In[191]:= Func[x_]:=If[Total[Map[#^3& ,IntegerDigits[x]]]==x,x,0];
Func[300]
```

> Out[192]= 300

Apparently the checking seems to be wrongly done. What caused this issue? How to fix it?

Comment: `Func[300]` returns 0 on my machine...

Comment: Have you reset the Kernel before? Maybe there is some old definition for `Func`. p.s. you don't have to `Map` in such cases: `Total[IntegerDigits[300]^3]` will do too.

Comment: @cormullion: Oh my ghost, I forgot to kill the kernel first.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We would like to find all integers `x` satisfying the following equation `Total[ IntegerDigits[x]^3] == x` (we don't have to map `#^3&` since `Power` is `Listable`).

**Warning:** Flexibility and polymorphism of *Mathematica* notation is restricted by [Operator Precedence](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/OperatorInputForms.html) (see also [When is f@g not the same as f[g]?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/30425/when-is-fg-not-the-same-as-fg/30430#30430)). It appears to be the case here. One could suspect this was the problem defining `Func` initially.

```
f[x_] := Total[ IntegerDigits[x]^3] == x
```

however we might get incorrect results using this definition `Total @ IntegerDigits @ x^3 == x` while this one works fine `Total[ IntegerDigits @ x^3] == x`.

```
Select[ Range[0, 10^5], f @ # &]
```

> ```
> {0, 1, 153, 370, 371, 407}
> ```

One can easily observe that we don't have to search for such integers anymore since `Total[ IntegerDigits[x]^3]` increases in a **polynomial rate**  with the exponent in `Range` while  `x` increases in an **exponential rate**  and

```
Total[ IntegerDigits[99999]^3] < 10^5
```

> ```
> True
> ```

Thus the above are all integers satisfying `Total[ IntegerDigits[x]^3] == x`.

**Edit**

Out of curiosity I have found how the solutions depend on the exponent. 
Defining:

```
f[x_, k_] := Total[ IntegerDigits[x]^k] == x
```

immediately we find with `Select[ Range[ 0, 10^4], f[#, 2]&]` that for `k == 2` there are no solutions (besides `0` and `1`).

```
ListPlot[ 
  Append[ 
    Table[ Log @ Total[ IntegerDigits[10^k - 1]^m], {m, 3, 9}, {k, 15}], 
    Table[ Log[ 10^(k - 1)], {k, 15}]], AxesOrigin -> {1, 0}, 
  PlotMarkers -> {Automatic, Medium}, PlotRange -> All, Joined -> True,
  PlotStyle -> Thick, PlotLegends -> Range[3, 9]]
```

[image]

With this plot it appears to be easier to estimate appropriate range of search space. 
We've got:

```
Select[ Range[10^6], f[#, 4]&]
```

> ```
> { 1, 1634, 8208, 9474}
> ```

```
Select[ Range[10^7], f[#, 5]&]
```

> ```
> { 1, 4150, 4151, 54748, 92727, 93084, 194979}
> ```

```
Select[ Range[5 10^7], f[#, 6]&]
```

> ```
> { 1, 548834}
> ```

Answer (score 2):

It works as Artes showed, but here's, not faster but why not, another approach:

```
func = (1 - Unitize[Norm[IntegerDigits[#], 3]^3 - #]) # &
```

for clarification, see the documentation for `Norm` and it's second argument.