# Order of operations, precedence in Mathematica

Tags: evaluation, expression-construction

I get confused in the order of operations in `Mathematica`.
For example,

```
f /@ 10^{1, 2, 3}
{10, 100, 1000}
```

In my head, that should be

```
{f[10], f[100], f[1000]}
```

After using `FullForm`, I see that my command should be regarded as : `(f /@ 10)^{1, 2, 3}`.
In fact, `()` is not often used in Mathematica code, and I'm always not sure about the order of the expression evaluation. And I can't find the information about this order.

For example, in *C*: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations

On MathWorld, it is just the basic : http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Precedence.html

1. Parenthesization,
2. Factorial,
3. Exponentiation,
4. Multiplication and division,
5. Addition and subtraction.

Another example: let look at the order of this:

```
x + x /. x -> y
2 y

x + (x /. x -> y)
x + y
```

And it takes time to understand this:

```
x + y /. x -> 1 + y + x /. x -> 5
6 + 2 y
```

Without the order of operations, one can get confused by interpret this expression, and of course, we can use ().

```
((x + y) /. x -> 1) +(( y + x) /. x -> 5)  
x + y /. x -> (1 + y + x) /. x -> 5
```

Another example, one can get confused:

```
Cases[{1, 2, 3}, _?#1 < 2 &]
```

or

```
Cases[{1, 2, 3}, _?(#1 < 2) &]
```

or

```
Cases[{1, 2, 3}, _?(#1 < 2 &)]
```

Another examples, which one `&` or `/.` is more privileged ?

```
x /. x -> y + #1 &

x + #1 & /. x -> y
```

I really appreciate any rule of thumbs or a guide of the operation ordered: `/@`, `@@`, `_?`, `/.`, `->`,`&` ...

Comment: see "when is f@g not the same as f[g]?" http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/30425/when-is-fg-not-the-same-as-fg  Operator Precedence Table is posted there by MrWizard and more discussion on the topic

Comment: Thank you ! That's what I want to find.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can check the precedence using `Precedence`. So for you first example it works that way because `Precedence[Power] < Precedence[Map]`. You have furthermore that `Precedence[Function] < Precedence[ReplaceAll]` for one of your later queries.

When you get confused and need to tell what the precedence is the fastest way though is to use `FullForm` and `Hold`. There are variations of this, I forget which one is considered best practice, but it works like this:

```
FullForm[Hold[f /@ 10^{1, 2, 3}]]
(* Out: Hold[Power[Map[f,10],List[1,2,3]]] *)
```

Comment: Be careful with `Precedence`, see my answer in the linked question.

Comment: @Kuba I didn't read all of the comments carefully but it looks like nit-picking to me. The basic operation of `Precedence` appears to be solid.

Comment: @I mean the answer, not a comment. What I want to say is that `Precedence@ReplaceAll` does not differ if it is `ReplaceAll[...]` or `.../.replacement` and the syntax does matter, not necessarily in this case, but it did in my answer.