# The order of evaluations with nested slots

Tags: evaluation, order, slot

I tried to join a series of evaluations with nested slots as follows:

```
#^2 & /@ #^2 & /@ Range[10]
```

However, the results were somewhat different from what I expected...

```
{1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81, 100}
```

The following code gave me the expected results:

```
#^2 & /@ (#^2 & /@ Range[10])
```

as

```
{1, 16, 81, 256, 625, 1296, 2401, 4096, 6561, 10000}
```

I assumed that nested slots would be evaluated from the outside. Do we have to use ugly parentheses in this case? Is there any smart way to handle a series of evaluations with slots?

Comment: The issue is actually with [operator precedence](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/40748/order-of-operations-precedence-in-mathematica). That's why you need the parentheses--because `Function (&)` binds more than `Map (/@)`. You can check out a symbol's precedence using the function `Precedence`.

Comment: Just use `Range[10]^2^2` or `Range[10]^4`

Comment: Or, you can compose: `Composition[#^2 &, #^2 &] /@ Range[10]`

Comment: I am surprised that things like `f/@2` does not produce errors.

Comment: @MB1965 unfortunately `Precedence` is useless in general, as shown in my naive answer in the linked topic :)

Comment: Satoshi, I marked this topic as a duplicate because I think the general topic is answerd in the first linked question and even more detailed `Map` discussion can be found in the second one. Though if you feel those topics do not answer your doubts let me know.

Comment: Kuba, thank you for your quick response. I think I could solve this issue (I thought it would be right-associated).

Comment: J.M., thank you. I think I can apply your suggestion to my problems.

Comment: Thank you for all the comments! It was helpful.