# I need to calculate sin[x] series summation for sin[A] where A is a 3X3 matrix

Tags: matrix

I am evaluating $\sin(A)$ where $A$ is a $3\times 3$ matrix. I have calculated it but now I want to check this with a Taylor series expansion of `Sin[x]`.
What I am using is

```
myfn= With[{B = N[A]}, 
            Sum[ MatrixPower[B, 2 k + 1]/Factorial[2 k + 1], {k, 0, 4}]]
```

But I have to put $(-1)^k$ as well in the summation list.
I dun know how to do it  either it takes $1$ or $-1$ but it's not changing a sign whenever I am trying to evaluate

```
With[{B = N[A]}, 
      Sum[ MatrixPower[B, 2 k + 1]*(-1^k)/ Factorial[2 k + 1], {k, 0, 4}]]
```

I am seriously stuck, could anyone help?

Comment: Did you mean to text this to someone called 'coz'? 
If not, please use the help facilities (upper right corner of page) to see how to properly format code in a post. You will have a better chance of getting assistance when readers aren't required to decipher the question.

Comment: Still, you might have wanted `MatrixFunction[]`.

Answer (score 5):

```
With[{B = N[A]}, 
      Sum[ MatrixPower[B, 2 k + 1]*((-1)^k)/ Factorial[2 k + 1], {k, 0, 4}]]
```

See [when is f@g not the same as f[g]?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/30425/when-is-fg-not-the-same-as-fg) under the *Operator Precedence* answer for why this is. Also, it's generally a bad idea to use uppercase for the initial, you can end up clashing with MM symbols (e.g. `E` is MM's symbol for `Euler's constant`.

Comment: Hi Rasher,Thanks alot for the answer. It really helped me becuase I was using different series for positive terms and different for negatvie terms in same expression to get the anser.