# Substitute a function's definition for its name

Tags: functions, function-construction, replacement, pure-function

I'm having trouble with a function which is supposed to work on another function. Simplified version:

```
one[x_] := 1 (* the argument *)
problem[f_] := Integrate[f[t], {t, 0, #}] & (* the function doing the work *)
```

Simple enough, right? But when I pass

```
problem[one] // InputForm (* to paste into se *)
```

I get

> Integrate[one[t], {t, 0, #1}] &

and even

```
FullSimplify[problem[one]] // InputForm
```

just gives

> Integrate[one[t], {t, 0, #1}] &

But I know that the function is there, since if I evaluate

```
problem[one][17]
```

it (properly) gives

> 17

How do I get Mathematica to substitute the function's definition for its name so it can simplify the result (in this case, evaluate the integral)?

(System details: 64-bit Mathematica 10.0.2.0, Windows 7 Pro SP1, i7-4770.)

Comment: So what you've defined with `problem` is what's called an anonymous or inline function. It's a function waiting to take arguments which will replace the `#`. That's why you don't get a result until you feed it the upper bound of your integral (17 in your example). Until then, it's just a function waiting for an argument to evaluate. What is it that you expect `problem[one]` to look like instead?

Comment: Try `Evaluate @@ problem[one]`

Comment: Proposed duplicate: [(41950)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/41950/121). Also related: [(30205)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/30205/121)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that the function name `f` is substituted into `Function` (`&`) which is [`HoldAll`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HoldAll.html).  This means `f[t]` will not be evaluated until the `Function` is evaluated, such as in the OP's example `problem[one][17]`.

So the trick is to evaluate the integrand before inserting it into the `Function`.  Here is one way.

```
one[x_] := 1 (*the argument*)
problem[f_] := With[{integrand = f[\[FormalT]]},
  Integrate[integrand, {\[FormalT], 0, #}] & 
  ]

problem[one]
(*  Integrate[1, {\[FormalT], 0, #1}] &  *)
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

As [@Guess who it is](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/50/guess-who-it-is) pointed out, the use of `\[FormalT]` or <kbd>Esc</kbd>`$t`<kbd>Esc</kbd> is safer way to define `problem`.  If ones uses a simple `t` instead and `t` already has a value, say `t = 2`, then the evaluation of `f[t]` will substitute the value of `t`, and we would get `f[2]` for the integrand instead of a function of `t`.  Since formal symbols cannot be assigned a value, this problem cannot occur with `\[FormalT]`.

However, if for some reason the definition of `f` contained `\[FormalT]`, say as a parameter, then we run into trouble.  So maybe a better way is to use `Module` to localize `t`.  This should offer even more protect at the expense of having a slightly unreadable module variable:

```
problem[f_] := Module[{t},
  With[{integrand = f[t]}, Integrate[integrand, {t, 0, #}] &]
  ]

problem[one]
(*  Integrate[1, {t$64741, 0, #1}] &  *)
```

Within one's own project, one should be able to pick a formal symbol that is never used as a parameter. So practically the first answer above should suffice.

Comment: Additional note: for full safety, one should consider using a formal symbol for the dummy variable.

Comment: @Guesswhoitis.: Can you explain how to do this? I recognized the (potential) problem of clashing variables but don't know how to handle this in Mathematica. (I can handle it in other languages, but my Math'ca isn't so good yet.)

Comment: @Charles, the idea is to use the formal symbols, `\[FormalA]` to `\[FormalZ]` (there are also upper-case versions, if needed) if you want to ensure that any dummy variable, as with sums and integrals, does not have a prior value that may have been set many cells ago. (They don't format nicely here on SE, but you should be able to see what they actually look like on the front end.) The keyboard shortcut for entering them in is Esc+\$+(letter here)+Esc.

Comment: @Charles I changed my answer to fit the comment.

Comment: I noted a proposed duplicate in the comments above.  I also note that this answer is more thorough than those.  Would you review the case and give your recommendation?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard The principle issues are the same.  The danger of unwanted evaluation is clearer in this question than in the proposed duplicate.  That seems main distinction.  I could vote for the duplicate and we could let the community decide whether it's distinctive enough to keep open.  Or did you have something else in mind?

Comment: I am not sure how to handle this so I asked.  At the very least they need to be linked, and now they are.  I *could* merge but that will cost you an Accept and require extensive rewriting; not ideal.  I always hesitate to close an older question in favor of a newer one but that too is an option.  Maybe I should leave well enough alone.