# Force evaluation of the right-hand side of a local variable definition

Tags: function-construction, evaluation, variable-definitions, assignment

One can do

```
expression = a + 1;

f[a_] := Evaluate[expression]
```

but how would one do something like this

```
expression = a + 1;

g[x_] := Module[{a,b},
  a=1;
  b=Evaluate[expression];
  x*b
 ]
```

so that only variable b right-hand side would be evaluated and not the whole Module. This would be useful for using long formulas generated by mathematica in own function definitions.

**The solution suitable for me:**

Thanks Jens for the answer, that pointed me to the right direction. The solution I was looking for and works for me is

```
expression = a + 1;

With[{expr=expression},
 f[x_]:=Block[{a,b},
   a = 1;
   b = expr;
   x*b
 ]
]
```

So using With outside of SetDelayed causes evaluation of expression as desired (Jens answer) and the naming problem (a and $a) is solved by using Block instead of Module.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: Relevant link, though not necessarily a duplicate due to `Module`: [Evaluation in lambda function](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/41950/245). There may well be other duplicate Q&As, but I haven't found one yet.

Answer (score 8):

There are two possibilities you could be aiming for. First, I'll take your question literally and just inject `expression` into the `Module`:

```
expression = a + 1;
With[{expression = expression},
 g[x_] := Module[
   {a, b},
   a = 1;
   b = expression;
   x*b]]

expression = 1

(* ==> 1 *)

g[xi]

(* ==> (1 + a) xi *)
```

As the result after changing `expression` shows, the earlier value of `expression` has been used in the definition of the `Module`. This was achieved by using `With` just as a wrapper that introduces the current value of `expression` *literally* in the definition of `g`.

However, this probably doesn't do what you expected, because the symbol `a` still appears in the last result. You *probably* wanted `a` to be replaced by `1`. This could for example be done as follows:

```
expression = a + 1;
With[{expression = expression /. a -> 1},
 h[x_] := Module[
   {b},
   b = expression;
   x*b]]

expression = 1

(* ==> 1 *)

h[xi]

(* ==> 2 xi *)
```

The reason that the definition `a=1;` for a local variable `a` inside the `Module` doesn't work is that *Mathematica* doesn't actually have local variables in the strict sense. Inside the `Module`, it renames `a` to something else (`a$`), but the injected `expression` was outside of the scope where this renaming happened. Therefore, `a` in `expression` isn't the same variable as `a` inside the `Module`. To avoid this mismatch, I do the replacement of `a` by `1` outside of the `Module`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Inactivate` and `Activate` to control the evaluation of the right-hand side.

```
expression = Inactivate[a + 1];

g[x_] :=
  x Activate[expression /. a -> 1];

g[2]
(* 4 *)

expression
(* a + 1 *)
```

`Inactivate` prevents the execution while `Activate` executes without losing the inactivated expression.

Hope this helps.