# Apply function to output of previous function

Tags: list-manipulation, functions, functional

I am trying to write a function that takes 3 tuples.  Each tuple contains two lists which are first divided.  This results in 3 lists.  Then I want to take the Mean of all the columns.  I can do this in two steps:

```
d = Divide[#1, #2] & @@@  { {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}}  , {{7, 8, 9}, {10,
  11, 12}} , {{13, 14, 15}, {16, 17, 18} } }
Mean[d]
```

However I would like to put this all on one line. I have tried a couple different things all smilar to

```
Mean[#] & @ Divide[#1, #2] & @@@  { {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}}  , {{7, 8, 9}, {10,
  11, 12}} , {{13, 14, 15}, {16, 17, 18} } }
```

The problem is the mean is not applied to the entire list but rather one level inside, which does not give the desired output.

the desired out put is:

```
{47/80, 608/935, 25/36}
```

Comment: Try the postfix `//` operator. So: `... // Mean`

Comment: closely related: [when is `f@g` not the same as `f[g]`](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/30425/5478)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
list = {{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}}, {{7, 8, 9}, {10, 11, 12}}, {{13, 14, 
     15}, {16, 17, 18}}};

Mean[Divide @@@ #] &@ list

Composition[Mean, Divide @@@ # &]@list

Divide @@@ list // Mean

Mean[Divide @@@ list]

Mean @ (Divide @@@ list)
```

It seems that first and the second may be considered the best since you don't have to put anything after the `list`.

Take a look at the topic I've linked too.

Comment: Aesthetically, the last one is the nicest.