# Association of pure functions

Tags: core-language, associations

I've encountered confusing behavior of Association when I try to use it for storing pure functions.

For example:

```
as = <|"1" -> # + 1 &|>
```

> Association["1" -> #1 + 1 &]

Strangely:

```
AssociationQ@as
```

> False

and it is not possible to extract the value by the key:

```
as["1"]
```

> Association["1" -> #1 + 1 &]["1"]

Is this the intended behavior?

P.S. Wrapping pure functions in Hold[] solves the problem, but I'm still curious why doesn't Association work without it.

Comment: I have closed this as a duplicate as the origin of the unexpected behavior is the same: the grouping of the `&` operator.  Please also see: [(30425)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/30425/121)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just add the parentheses

```
as = <|"1" -> (# + 1 &)|>
(* <|"1" -> (#1 + 1 &)|> *)

AssociationQ@as
(* True *)
```

`Rule` (`->`) has lower precedence then `&`.