# Is there an internal logic behind short form symbols, such as @ (Prefix), @@ (Apply), /@ (Map), /. (ReplaceAll)

Tags: functions, syntax, language-design

To me, function names (such as `Apply` and `Map`) seem more intuitive than their symbols (e.g. `@@` and `./@`). However, I wish I could internalized what these short form symbols mean and do. (I know that that they are very helpful and could help make my code much more readable.)

So, I was wondering...

*Is there an internal logic behind the short forms?*

I imagine that they could be related by the meaning of the individual elements (e.g., `@`, `.`, `/`) and the ordering of these elements to build (e.g., `@@`, `/@`, `/.`}.

Here is a list of short forms symbols that seem similar and/or related. (Please feel free to edit and add more)

```
@   Prefix[] 
@@  Apply[]
@@@ Apply[ , , {1}]
/@  Map[]
//@ MapAll[]
/.  ReplaceAll[]
//. ReplaceRepeated[]
//  Postfix[]
~  Infix[]
```

Comment: ~ Infix          .................

Comment: Have you seen [What the @#%^&*?! do all those funny signs mean?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/25616/5478) and a little bit related: [Operator Precedence Table](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/30430/5478)

Comment: @Kuba, thanks for the great references! Those definitely help.