# Simplify list of rules

Tags: simplifying-expressions

How to simplify list of rules? For example,

```
{{a -> 0},{a -> 0, b -> 0}, {a -> 0, c -> 0}}
```

should return `{{a->0}}` since $(a=0)||(a=0\&\&b=0)||(a=0\&\&c=0)=(a=0)$.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To explain the other answerer's response, what you need to do is convert the rules into logical expressions, as a `Rule` in the Wolfram Language just turns the left hand side into the right hand side.  So the first step is to make all the `Rule`s into `Equal`s:

```
rules = {{a -> 0},{a -> 0, b -> 0}, {a -> 0, c -> 0}};

rules2 = ReplaceAll[rules, Rule -> Equal]
(*{{a == 0}, {a == 0, b == 0}, {a == 0, c == 0}}*)
```

*ReplaceAll takes anything matching a given pattern, in this case `Rule`, and replaces it with another expression, in this case `Equal`*

Then you need to make this a logical `And` expression, like this:

```
rules3 = Apply[And, rules2, {1}]
(*{a == 0, a == 0 && b == 0, a == 0 && c == 0}*)
```

*`Apply` changes the head of the second argument to the first argument.  The third argument defines which level it happens on*

Then you need to make the list into a logical `Or` expression:

```
rules4 = Apply[Or, rules3]
(*a == 0 || (a == 0 && b == 0) || (a == 0 && c == 0)*)
```

Finally you use `LogicalExpand` to convert this statement into it's simplest form:

```
LogicalExpand[rules4]
(*a == 0*)
```

The shorthand posted previously is from the shorthands of `ReplaceAll` and `Apply`.

`@@` means `Apply`

`@@@` means `Apply` at level one

`/.` means `ReplaceAll`

`//` is suffix notation, so it does the right hand side on the left hand side.

Put together this makes the short version:

```
Or @@ And @@@ rules /. Rule -> Equal // LogicalExpand
```

Comment: Great explanation. You could maybe even add something about the order with which the shorthands are evaluated. By experience, I know it's evaluated as such `((Or @@ (And @@@ rules)) /. Rule -> Equal) // LogicalExpand` but I couldn't "prove" it.

Comment: @anderstood See [when is `f@g` not the same as `f[g]`?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/30425/when-is-fg-not-the-same-as-fg)

Answer (score 10):

```
Or @@ And @@@ r /. Rule -> Equal // LogicalExpand
```

Comment: If you want to have a rule in the end, you have to replace it back after the expression is simplified like this: `{Or @@ And @@@ r /. Rule -> Equal // LogicalExpand} /. Equal -> Rule`

Comment: @Stitch yep, there are also double brackets but I decided that should be enough and OP should be able to adjust it for specific needs.