# Change Operator Precedence of --> operator

Tags: replacement, operators, precedence

I am trying to use `-->` operator with highest precedence

```
Unprotect[LongRightArrow];
LongRightArrow[obj_,property_]:=obj[ToString[property]];
Protect[LongRightArrow];
```

With this I can do basic operations like accessing properties of an association

```
In:=  obj = <|"a" -> {2, 3}, "b" -> 5|>
Out:= <|"a" -> {2, 3}, "b" -> 5|>
In:=  obj⟶a
Out:= {2, 3}
```

However when I try to access elements of list in `obj-->a` `Part` takes higher precedence. Same applies for operator `^`.

```
In:=  obj⟶a[[1]]
Out:= Missing["KeyAbsent", "a[[1]]"]
In:=  obj⟶a^2
Out:= Missing["KeyAbsent", "2 a"]
```

Comment: `LongRightArrow` doesn't have any built in precedence, according to http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/OperatorInputForms.html.  You might be able to use http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PrecedenceForm.html

Comment: what should `obj-->Part[a,1]` do?

Comment: not should but I want to change precedence such that it returns 2, (without affect other operations)

Comment: Do you mean you want `obj-->a[[1]]` to be interpreted as `Part[obj-->a,1]` and not `obj-->Part[a,1]` ? Or do you actually want `obj-->Part[a,1]` to give  `2`?  @george2079 I think if he is talking about precedence he means the first.

Comment: Yes I want the first one.

Comment: However if there exists any other method that gives `2` from `obj-->Part[a,1]` without altering precedence, I would like to learn that too

Comment: I've tried using `Notation` But that didn't work

Comment: it seems you need to modify `Part` somehow, or do you want to map to the first argument of any function, `obj-->f[x]  -> f[obj-->x]`

Comment: `Part` is not the only problem, this happens with other operators also, `^` is one such example

Answer (score 10, accepted):

How about overloading the `LongRightArrow` with a special rule for `Part[...]` as the second argument?

```
Unprotect[LongRightArrow];
SetAttributes[LongRightArrow, HoldRest]
LongRightArrow[obj_, property_] := obj[ToString[property]];
LongRightArrow[obj_, Part[property_, partspec__]] := 
Part[LongRightArrow[obj, property], partspec];
Protect[LongRightArrow];
obj = <|"a" -> {2, 3}, "b" -> 5|>
obj⟶a
obj⟶a[[1]]
```

> ```
> <|"a" -> {2, 3}, "b" -> 5|>
> {2, 3}
> 2
> ```

Chip Hurst was quicker than I to show the generalization

```
LongRightArrow[obj_, head_[f_, args__]] := head[LongRightArrow[obj, f], args]
```

So I'll just take one more step to handle unary postfix operators, such as `!` (`Factorial`). Trivial by replacing `args__` with `args___`:

```
LongRightArrow[obj_, head_[f_, args___]] := head[LongRightArrow[obj, f], args]
```

Now

```
obj⟶a!
```

> ```
> {2, 6}
> ```

**EDIT**
Re the comment:

```
obj⟶a⟶b
```

is equivalent to

```
LongRightArrow[obj, a, b]
```

while the desired behavior is

```
LongRightArrow[LongRightArrow[obj, a], b]
```

Well, obviously, that's exactly what we should tell Mathematica, it can't guess that for us.

```
LongRightArrow[obj_, a_, b__] := LongRightArrow[LongRightArrow[obj, a], b]
obj⟶a⟶b⟶b⟶b⟶b⟶b
```

> ```
>  (((((obj⟶a)⟶b)⟶b)⟶b)⟶b)⟶b
> ```

Comment: But this is not generic what about operator^ ?

Comment: @Neel True. Replace Part with a named pattern. I'll add an example once back at the computer.

Comment: Thanks, This works fine. However what about `obj-->x-->y` ? Now it works  only if I bracket  `(obj-->x)-->y`

Comment: @NeelBasu what do you expect from that expression? Its `FullForm` is `LongRightArrow[obj, a, b]`; you never proposed a rule for that in the first place.

Comment: `obj-->x-->y` to be evaluated as `(obj-->x)-->y`

Comment: @NeelBasu here you go (see edit)

Answer (score 8):

You could give `LongRightArrow` a `HoldRest` attribute and manipulate the right hand side.

Perhaps something like:

```
SetAttributes[LongRightArrow, HoldRest]

LongRightArrow[obj_, head_[f_, args__]] := head[LongRightArrow[obj, f], args]

LongRightArrow[obj_, f_] := obj[ToString[f]]
```

Test:

```
obj⟶a
```

> ```
> {2, 3}
> ```

```
obj⟶a[[1]]
```

> ```
> 2
> ```

```
obj⟶a^2
```

> ```
> {4, 9}
> ```

Comment: Looks like my answer near-verbatim ;-)

Comment: @LLlAMnYP Ah, I didn't see your answer until now...

Comment: Well now we have somewhat complementary answers. +1

Answer (score 6):

The precedence of LongRightArrow is predetermined as shown in the [operator table.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/30430/121)  You can attempt to circumvent the problem as other answers show but these *do not* change the binding power of the operator itself.

As you can see from the table `Part` has especially high binding power.  What you want therefore goes against the design of *Mathematica* in some way; one would *expect* `obj⟶(a[[1]])` rather than `(obj⟶a)[[1]]`.

If you want to supersede `Part` you might consider something with natively higher binding power though there aren't many choices; [`Overscript`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Overscript.html) is one:

```
Overscript[obj_, property_] := obj[ToString[property]];
```

Now entered using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>7</kbd>:

[image]

Manually parenthesizing i.e. actually writing `(obj⟶a)[[1]]` is another option:

```
(obj⟶a)[[1]]
```

> ```
> 2
> ```

**Note:** you do not need to [`Unprotect`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Unprotect.html) `Overscript` or `LongRightArrow` as these operators are intended for use.

Comment: Good catch about the absence of a `Protected` attribute. +1

Answer (score 5):

If you don't mind mucking with the internal file `UnicodeCharacters.tr` (make a copy first!) you can change the line:

```
0x27F6 ⟶ ($-->$ $&LongRightArrow;$ $\longrightarrow$) Infix   650 None    2   2
```

to:

```
0x27F6 ⟶ ($-->$ $&LongRightArrow;$ $\longrightarrow$) Infix   750 Left    2   2
```

and then close and relaunch Mathematica so that the changes take affect. Afterwards I get:

```
obj⟶a[[1]]
```

> 2

and:

```
obj⟶a^2
```

> {4, 9}

Also, the grouping change means:

```
obj⟶a⟶b //Hold //FullForm
```

> Hold[LongRightArrow[LongRightArrow[obj,a],b]]

gets parsed the way you want.

Comment: This is a great bit of knowledge, and the only answer here that really gets to the heart of the matter! Thanks! Is there somewhere I could read about the internal structure of Mathematica? (I'm looking to do other syntax-affecting things as well, like introducing new tokens—though that might be more complicated.)