# Changing operator precedence

Tags: symbolic, built-in-symbols

Is there a way to change operator precedence for built-in symbols?

I'd like `\[TensorProduct]` (which I redefine to `KroneckerProduct`) to take precedence after dot, so that the following is true

```
A.B\[TensorProduct]C.D == (A.B)\[TensorProduct](C.D)
```

Comment: Related:  [140609](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/140609/operator-precedence-of-operator).  People tend to suggest workarounds rather than actual ways to change operator precedence.  **Edit** You might give `TensorProduct` a `HoldAll` attribute and define **down**values (to TensorProduct)  when a `Dot` object appears in `TensorProduct`.

Comment: Also, how exactly do you redefine `\[TensorProduct]` to `KroneckerProduct`?

Comment: I do `TensorProduct=KroneckerProduct`

Comment: How about using `CircleTimes = KroneckerProduct` and then `A.B\[CircleTimes]C.D`

Answer (score 7):

If you enter `\[TensorProduct]` using the input alias `t*`, then you can override the input alias to produce a [`TemplateBox`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TemplateBox) with a [`SyntaxForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SyntaxForm) setting to lower the precedence:

```
CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], {InputAliases,"t*"}]=TemplateBox[
    {},
    "TensorProduct",
    DisplayFunction->("\[TensorProduct]"&),
    InterpretationFunction:>(Sequence["~","TensorProduct","~"]&),
    SyntaxForm->"*"
];
```

Your example (as an image to show the alias in action):

[image]