# why does mapping ValueQ produce surprising results?

Tags: core-language

```
ClearAll[f1, f2]
f1[x_] := x*x
f2 = #*# &;
```

This produces the expected results:

```
ValueQ[f1]  (* False *)
ValueQ[f2]  (* True *)
```

I find this unexpected:

```
ValueQ /@ {f1, f2}  (* {False,False} *)
```

How can I understand the difference?

Comment: There is a documentation example about this; use `ValueQ /@ Unevaluated[{f1, f2}]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `ValueQ /@ {f1, f2}` the expression `{f1, f2}` is evaluated before `ValueQ` is applied, therefore `ValueQ` never "sees" `f2`, only its value `#*# &` which itself does not have a value.

It is critical to understand the standard evaluation order in *Mathematica* or you shall be chasing many problems or surprises of this nature.  Recommended reading:

- [Tutorial: Evaluation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/Evaluation.html)
- [Tutorial: Non-Standard Evaluation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NonStandardEvaluation.html)
- [Working with Unevaluated Expressions - Robby Villegas](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Courseware/377/)

Operator precedence is also critical unless you exclusively use bracketed notation; see:

- [when is f@g not the same as f[g]?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/30425/121)

Comment: Thanks.  I forgot that `ValueQ` has the `HoldFirst` attribute, which should have been obvious.