# What does the @ symbol do in Mathematica?

Tags: matrix, pure-function, inverse

I have the folllowing array

$$h = \left(\begin{array}{cccc}1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
                                   0 & f^2 & 0 & f^2 \cos\theta\\
                                   0 & 0 & g^2 & 0 \\
                                   0 & f^2\cos\theta & 0 & f^2\cos^2\theta + g^2\sin^2\theta\end{array}\right)$$

defined in Mathematica using

```
h = {{1,0,0,0},{0,f^2,0,f^2 Cos[theta],{0,0,g^2,0},{0,f^ Cos[theta],0,f^2 Cos[theta]^2 + g^2 Sin[theta]^2}};
```

If I now have a matrix $M$ of the same dimension as $h$, and if I do the following operation:

```
Mprime = Simplify[M.Inverse@g];
```

what will this achieve?

**More precisely** what does the code

```
Matrix1.Inverse@Matrix2
```

actually end up doing?

Comment: See linked topic,especially: [What the @#%^&*?! do all those funny signs mean?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/25616/5478).

Comment: See also: [when is f@g not the same as f\[g\]?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/30425/5478)

Comment: p.s. lookup `Cos` and documentation in general because `f^2\cos\theta` is not close to a valid syntax.

Comment: @Kuba, thanks for the links. As for the commands, that was a typo which I've fixed now. I entered the LaTeX code instead of the Mathematica code. :)