# Replace variable in Series expression

Tags: output-formatting, replacement, series-expansion

I am trying to generate a series expansion in terms of the variable `t` then substitute a value in for it.  However it seems that something about the SeriesData object returned by `Series` doesn't permit a standard slashdot replacement.

```
Series[(a^4 - (a - t)^4), {t, 0, 4}] // Normal /. t -> a/20
```

returns

```
4 a^3 t - 6 a^2 t^2 + 4 a t^3 - t^4
```

which is the same result as though the slashdot isn't even there.

On the other hand, replacing prior to `Normal` results in an undesirable output.

```
Series[a^4 - (a - t)^4 , {t, 0, i}] /. t -> a/20 // Normal
```

returns

```
(4 a^3 a)/20 - 6 a^2 (a/20)^2 + 4 a (a/20)^3 - (a/20)^4 + O[a/20]^6
```

This is on the right track, but I am left with the BigO and no amount of `Simplify` or its related functions can get the expression to condense to `C*a^4`.

To further complicate things, I am trying to run this within a `For` loop where I increment the number of kept terms.

```
For[i = 1, i <= 4, i++, 
 Print[Series[a^4 - (a - t)^4), {t, 0, i}] // Normal /. t -> a/20]]
```

So, how can I do the Series expansion, substitute `a/20` in for `t`, and get a nice output that is, ideally, some constant times `a^4`.  Much thanks.

Comment: `Normal@Series[(a^4 - (a - t)^4), {t, 0, 4}] /. t -> a/20`. Operator precedence. in other words, implicitly, your original expression is interpreted like this: `Series[(a^4 - (a - t)^4), {t, 0, 4}] // (Normal /. t -> a/20)`.

Comment: That's a notation with which I am unfamiliar.  But thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(As [march](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/29734/march) beat me to comment) I think you have a precedence problem with the postfix application `//`.  Try this:

```
(Series[(a^4 - (a - t)^4), {t, 0, 4}] // Normal) /. t -> a/20
```

> ```
> (29679 a^4)/160000
> ```

Comment: Unbelievable.  So that I fully understand and never repeat this mistake:  Without the parenthesis, Mathematica is trying to do the replacement within Normal itself?

Comment: @saintsfan342000 Yes!  I realize this is probably annoying but it follows from standard [precedence rules.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/30430/121) This is actually useful in other cases, once you know to expect it.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard From a software design standpoint I find this precedence choice to be a flaw.  On no occasion have I ever wanted to do a replacement only on the suffixed function; I always want to replace on the entire thing to the left.  Do you know why it is designed this way?

Comment: @QuantumDot I am very tired from exercise and probably not thinking at my best.  However if I am not mistaken the explanation is easy: each operator only has one binding power, i.e. the left and right sides are treated similarly.  (continued)

Comment: If `/.` had a lower binding power then things like `{1, 2, 3} /. {2 -> 7} // Print` would group like `{1, 2, 3} /. ({2 -> 7} // Print)` which is totally undesirable in most cases in my experience. `//` is specifically useful because of its low binding power allowing *most* things on the left-hand-side to "stay together."  That the right hand side, e.g. `// Normal /. t -> a/20` is also grouped together is merely an unfortunate consequence, though this too can *at least occasionally* be exploited usefully.