# Chaining map and abstract functions -- when (and why) is parenthesization necessary?

Tags: function-construction, map

I am a bit confused with how do some expressions in Mathematica get parsed. I was using a combination of map (`/@`) and abstract functions of the form `F[#, _param_]&`, and ran into the following problem.

This code does not work properly (it seems that `G` is not applied):

```
G[#, _params_]& /@ F[#, _params_]& /@ myList
```

But if I parenthesize the abstract function `F`, it works properly:

```
G[#, _params_]& /@ (F[#, _params_]&) /@ myList
```

Also works if i close the parenthesis at the very end.

Why is this happening? Why does the first example not work? When do I need to add parentheses in such chains in general?

As I am not sure how general this issue is, I attach the code where I encountered the problem. I have a list of strings that I imported, and want to first trim it, and then split it (so that I can convert it to expression next)

```
myList = {" \"2, 3\"", " \"2, 14\""}
```

```
In: StringSplit[#, ","] & /@ StringTrim[#, ("\"" | " ") ...] & /@ myList
Out: {"2, 3", "2, 14"}
```

```
In: StringSplit[#, ","] & /@ (StringTrim[#, ("\"" | " ") ...] &) /@ myList
Out: {{"2", " 3"}, {"2", " 14"}}
```

As you can see, in the first case, the `StringSplit` was not applied.

Comment: Compare results of `G[#] & /@ F[#] & /@ {a, b, c} // Trace` and `G[#] & /@ (F[#] &) /@ {a, b, c} // Trace`, you will see how parentheses set the order of computations.

Comment: This avoids ambiguity of pure functions. `myList // StringReplace[{" " -> "", "\"" -> ""}] // 
  StringSplit[#, ","] & // ToExpression`

Comment: I changed "brackets", which are `[]`, to "parentheses", which are `()`.  Roll back if you really meant brackets.

Comment: It is a question of precedence.  See [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/30430/4999) for references and general discussion. It is also mentioned specifically about `&` in the 3rd paragraph [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users/25616#25616).

Comment: Syntax highlighting also indicates precedence and syntactical scope of a function in an expression as you move the cursor around.

Comment: So the problem here is low precedence of ```&```, makes sense. I'm not really sure why does the version without parentheses work at all now, but I see why does it not do what I want. Thank you for the answers! Also, thanks @Michael for the edit, I meant, indeed, parentheses.

Comment: The answer is essentially there, so I guess we can mark it as duplicate