# Is it possible to pipe(afterthought apply function) with options?

Tags: syntax, core-language

**For example**, I have the following

```
hexToRGB = RGBColor @@ (IntegerDigits[#~StringDrop~1~FromDigits~16, 256, 3]/255.) &;

Image@hexToRGB["#99c361"] // DominantColors["HexRGBColor"] (* why not? *)
```

To be clear, I am well aware that I can write

```
DominantColors[#, 1, "HexRGBColor"] &@Image@hexToRGB["#99c361"]
```

But there doesn't seem to be a postfix form for pure functions, or is there?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because currying is not performed automatically. But you can do the following:

```
Image@hexToRGB["#99c361"] // DominantColors[#, 1, "HexRGBColor"] &
```

Comment: Awesome thanks, is there a way to combine this w/ the prefix form e.g. `First[#]&@Image@hexToRGB["#99c361"] // DominantColors[#, 1, "HexRGBColor"] &` ?

Comment: ah nvm, just need to add parentheses

Comment: @skyfire Syntax precedence determines the order `@` and `//` are applied.  My guess is that you want `Image@hexToRGB["#99c361"] // First@ DominantColors[#, 1, "HexRGBColor"] &`

Comment: @MichaelE2 Yes, that is better than mine. Sort of confused on how mathematica parses its expressions now though. The 3 methods in this answer make it unclear how the expression gets evaluated.

Comment: @skyfire The [precedence](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/30425/when-is-fg-not-the-same-as-fg/30430#30430) of `//` is very low, lower than `@`; that of `&` is even lower.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Ah I understand now. Is there a reference on operator precedence's?

Comment: The link in my comment is to an answer discussing precedence, which also includes a link to a tutorial in the docs.

Answer (score 5):

You can define an operator form for `DominantColors` by modifying its definition:

```
Unprotect[DominantColors]
DominantColors[s_String] := DominantColors[#, 1, s] &; 
Protect[DominantColors];
```

A better/safer alternative is to define your own function with its operator form that works like the function `DominantColors`:

```
ClearAll[dominantColors]
dominantColors[a__, o : OptionsPattern[DominantColors]] := DominantColors[a, o]
dominantColors[s_String] := dominantColors[#, 1, s] &

"#99c361" // hexToRGB // Image // dominantColors["HexRGBColor"] // First
```

> ```
> "#99c361"
> ```

```
First @ dominantColors["HexRGBColor"] @ Image @ hexToRGB @ "#99c361"
```

> ```
>  "#99c361"
> ```

Comment: nice, was not aware of `OptionsPattern[]`

Comment: @skyfire You can also use `OptionsPattern[DominantColors]` to restrict to the options of `DominantColors`.

Comment: Thank you @MichaelE2. I added the argument to `OptionsPattern`.