# Why does Replace `/.` not get evaluated in this formula?

Tags: replacement, syntax

Learning the wolfram Language, in [section 32](https://www.wolfram.com/wolfram-u/an-elementary-introduction-to-the-wolfram-language/32-patterns.en.html)

```
"The Wolfram Language" // Characters[#]& /. Alternatives @@Characters["aeiou"] -> Nothing
```

Returns
`{T,h,e, ,W,o,l,f,r,a,m, ,L,a,n,g,u,a,g,e}`

I expected it to return
`{T,h, ,W,l,f,r,m, ,L,n,g,g}`

Changing it to

```
Characters["The Wolfram Language"] /. Alternatives @@Characters["aeiou"] -> Nothing
```

Returns the expected result, why?

Comment: Be careful with afterthought (`//`) notation. In this case, everything after `//` is grouped together. You can see this by repeatedly clicking `Characters` and see how the selection expands. You'd need to write `("The Wolfram Language" // Characters[#]&) /. ...` to make this work.

Comment: Related: [(30425)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/30425/when-is-fg-not-the-same-as-fg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Characters[#] & /. Alternatives @@ Characters["aeiou"] -> Nothing` is processed together.  You can see this by quadruple-clicking on `Characters[#]` -- the extended highlighting shows the operator associations and order of processing.

Processing the operations together is equivalent to constructing `f`, as here:

```
f = Characters[#] & /. Alternatives @@ Characters["aeiou"] -> Nothing;

"The Wolfram Language" // f
```

> {T,h,e, ,W,o,l,f,r,a,m, ,L,a,n,g,u,a,g,e}

As well as the method you show, the operator binding can be fixed like this:

```
ReplaceAll["The Wolfram Language" // Characters[#] &, 
 Alternatives @@ Characters["aeiou"] -> Nothing]
```

> {T,h, ,W,l,f,r,m, ,L,n,g,g}

Comment: I'm on wolfram cloud, does quadruple clicking work there? It seems not to. Also, is there a way to modify execution order with parentheses, etc?

Comment: Ah, this does work: `("The Wolfram Language"//Characters[#]&)/.Alternatives@@Characters["aeiou"]->Nothing` Gotcha, that's helpful

Comment: So, essentially, I should think about `//` not as piping syntax (as I'm used to from shell scripts) but rather as a convenient lambda creator. It takes everything prior to the `//` and treats it as arguments and everything after `//` and treats it as a function

Comment: You may find this informative: [Special Ways to Input Expressions](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/Expressions.html#3012)  : i.e. "*You should notice that // has very low precedence.* "