# Adding numbers with defined precision produces incorrect result

Tags: numerics, precision-and-accuracy, machine-precision, broken-code

I've tracked a bug in my code down to the problem of adding two numbers together, with the left argument having machine precision, e.g by `` 3` `` . The issue is, if there is no space between the two numbers, then the addition acts on the *precision* of the number and not the number itself. For example,

`` 3`+2 `` produces  `3.0` instead of  `5.`.

additionally, if we specify a numerical value for the precision, we get the correct result with specified precision:

`` 3`2+2 `` produces `5.00`

There is no space between the two arguments and the addition sign. If we add spaces:

`` 3`+ 2 `` produces `5.`

`` 3` + 2 `` produces `5.`

This possible bug caused me a big headache in my code. Is there a way to globally remove this from the notebook so that I get the expected result from, e.g. `` 3`+2=5. ``? I couldnt find anything in the documentation regarding this issue.

Some possibly relevant information:

My mathematica version is
Version 13.0.1 for Linux x86 (64-bit)

Comment: For information about operator/input precedence see [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/30425/when-is-fg-not-the-same-as-fg).  Note that `Precedence[Precision]==670.` and `Precedence[Plus]==310.`, so an ambiguously entered input expression gives precedence to the backtick precedence rather than the +.

Comment: See https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/InputSyntax.html#7977 for the definition of the input ``number`s`` where `s` may be a decimal real number or integer.

Answer (score 4):

This is a well-known problem of parsing of ambiguous input in *Mathematica*.

If you enter `` 3`+2 ``, it is correctly parsed as arbitrary precision number 3 with precision 2:

```
3`+2 // InputForm
```

> ```
> 3.`2.
> ```

If you include a space between the backtick and the plus sign, it will be interpreted as an addition of machine precision number 3 with exact number 2:

```
3` + 2
```

> ```
> 5.
> ```

Alternatively, you can specify that a number is a `MachinePrecision` number just by placing the dot right after it (in this case the presence or absence of the spaces between the dot and the plus sign does not matter):

```
3. + 2
```

> ```
> 5.
> ```

---

> Is there a way to globally remove this from the notebook so that I get the expected result from, e.g. `` 3`+2=5. ``?

If I type in the "Find and Replace" dialog `` `+ `` (without a space) in the "Find:" field, and `` ` + `` (with the space character between the backtick and the plus sign) in the "Replace with:" field, I'm able to replace all the occurences, and obtan the result you wish (I'm on *Mathematica* 13.1.0).

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

Here I have a different take from @AlexeyPopkov (+1), as I think taking care of the number of spaces in an expression is not a desirable programming strategy for *Mathematica*, so our analysis is equivalent but our solutions or advice are different.

## Analysis

The key point was made by @evanb, your expression

```
3`+2
```

Has two operators competing, `SetPrecision` and `Plus` and

```
Precedence[SetPrecision]>Precedence[Plus]
(* True *)
```

So it gets interpreted as

```
SetPrecision[3,Plus[2]]
```

and then

```
SetPrecision[3,2]
```

as `Plus[2]==2`, so you get a low precision `3` as output. On the other hand, with a space

```
3` +2
```

is unambiguous, the space breaks the ambiguity, no need to check precedence, and therefore interpreted as

```
Plus[SetPrecision[3,MachinePrecision],2]
```

which is `5.` with `MachinePrecision`.

## Solution

I would suggest avoiding potentially ambiguous and hard-to-debug expressions like

```
3`+2
```

and instead, use `FullForm` syntax to input your code, as such is the most unambiguous way to get the behaviour you expect.

```
Plus[SetPrecision[3,MachinePrecision],2]
```

Taking care of the number of spaces in an expression is not a desirable programming strategy for Mathematica.

Comment: I should stress that `$MachinePrecision` and `MachinePrecision` are completely diffrent things. The first forces the arbitrary precision arithmetics, while the second is the actual machine precision number. You can see with ``Precision[3`]`` returning `MachinePrecision` that it is a `MachinePrecision` number, not an arbitrary precision. But ``Precision[SetPrecision[3, $MachinePrecision]]`` returns ``15.954589770191003`` what means that with `SetPrecision[3, $MachinePrecision]` you get an arbitrary precision number.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov thanks for the comment, I amended my answer.

Comment: Further, addition of any number to a machine precision number gives a machine precision number.

Comment: Corrected again @AlexeyPopkov, thanks