# Difference between @ and @@

Tags: functions, syntax

I am confused by the commands `@` and `@@`. From the documentation, I learnt that `@@` is the function `Apply`. However, if I input `Cos@@5` the output is 5, while if I input `Cos@5`, I get `Cos[5]`. By this it seems that `@` rather than `@@` has the function of "apply".

When I tried the function `Plus`, `Plus@@{1,2}` gave me 3 as desired, while `Plus@{1,2}` just gave me `{1,2}`. Could anyone help me with the difference (or relation) between `@` and `@@`?

Comment: These are discussed in the answers to this question: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5432/syntax-for-prefix-mode-with-multiple-arguments-using-shorthand  The `@@` is described at length in the documentation for [`Apply`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Apply.html).  `@` is harder to find in the documentation: see [`Prefix`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Prefix.html),

Comment: @Kuba, actually the documentation isn't great on these shortcuts.  Nintety five percent of the time, I access the documentation on a function via `?FunctionName`.  But when you do type in `?@` you get nothing useful, likewise for `@@`.  So my next step is usually a web search, but "at symbol mathematica" doesn't really return any useful results in Google either.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica. Your question is very reasonable, as Jason points out.  @ is the only function in Mathematica I can think of that apparently has no name in English.

Comment: @Kuba, when I type `?@@` inside a notebook, that is not what I get as the output.  To find that, I have to specifically open up the documentation center from the Help menu and type it into the search box.

Comment: @Hector I like the discussion but it is offtopic so I vote for deleting those comments to not confuse others. I admit that documentation is not perfect :).

Comment: @DavidCarraher Actually I find `Prefix` is confusing. The input `f@x` is processed to be equivalent to `f[x]`, and is not the same as `Prefix`.  The `@` sign as input is interpreted by syntax rules; I don't think it is translated as a real function.  I realize on rereading what I wrote above is rather misleading!  This is a better reference: http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/SpecialWaysToInputExpressions.html

Comment: @JasonB If you select `@@` and execute the menu command Help > Find Selected Function (cmd-shift-F on a Mac or F1 on Windows) you get a link to the page for Apply respectively.  For `@`, you get a link to `Prefix`, which is not [what is wanted](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/SpecialWaysToInputExpressions.html).  This has been mentioned before on this site, but I can't find where.

Comment: Related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/30425/when-is-fg-not-the-same-as-fg

Comment: @MichaelE2 Your clarification is helpful. So `Prefix` is not the same as `@` and the latter remains nameless.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the difference between prefix/postfix notations and map?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/19219/what-is-the-difference-between-prefix-postfix-notations-and-map)

Answer (score 23):

I can see the source of your confusion: If you use `Head[f[x]]` and `Head[5]` you get `f` and `Integer` respectively. Then, you read the documentation

> Apply[f,expr] or f@@expr replaces the head of expr by f.

and you expect `Cos@@5` to replace the `Integer` head by `Cos`. The way I explain it to myself is by saying Mathematica has two (types of) heads ;-) One type is for expressions such as `f[x]` and the other is for expressions such as `5`. I even have names for them: explicit and implicit heads. Then I conclude: `Apply` replaces explicit heads only.

Now, in `{1,2}`, the head is an explicit one. Thus, `Plus@@{1,2}=Plus@@List[1,2]=Plus[1,2]=3`.

The `@` symbol is easier to understand. `f@x` is just `f[x]`. So, `Plus@{1,2}=Plus[List[1,2]]` and the result is `List[1,2]` because you are not adding anything to `List[1,2]`. If you want to add something to `List[1,2]`, it must be included as another parameter to `Plus`. Try `Plus[List[1,2],a]`.

---

As mentioned in the comments, the documentation does not warn about these two types of heads. If you look closely, you will find a warning in Possible Issues in [Apply](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Apply.html) and in the 3rd statement within details in [AtomQ](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/AtomQ.html?q=AtomQ&lang=en). I would have expected some clarification in [Everything Is an Expression](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/EverythingIsAnExpression.html). A naive reading of it suggests that `5` and `Integer[5]` are the same thing.

Comment: The chief difference between the two is the whether `AtomQ` returns `True` or not. If it does, then `Apply` doesn't work on it.

Comment: Even understanding that distinction, is there some sense to `f@@5` simply discarding the `f` ?  Some example where that is actually used?

Comment: @Hector Thanks for your comment. It makes sense to me. Could you say more about the meaning of 'Head'. The help document gives some examples, but doesn't give a description or a definition.

Comment: @george2079: In `f@@5`, the problem is not about "discarding" the `f` but rather that there is no (explicit) head to be replaced. Again, `f@@Integer[5] = f[5]` because `Integer[5]` has an explicit head `Integer`. On the other hand, `5` also has head `Integer` but it is implicit. Implicit heads are useful for pattern matching, but they are not really there ...

Comment: @hongchaniyi: After you read this link: [Everything is an Expression](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/EverythingIsAnExpression.html), play with [TreeForm](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/TreeForm.html?q=TreeForm&lang=en).

Comment: @george2079 an "exception" to what Hector said about explicit heads is `Complex`. `AtomQ[Complex[1, 2]]` returns `True`, but it is interpreted as a single indivisible (except mathematically) unit.

Comment: @george2079: An "exception" to what rcollyer wrote about `AtomQ` is the following: `myAtom /: AtomQ[myAtom[__]] := True; f@@myAtom[1, 2, 3]` returns `f[1, 2, 3]` even though `AtomQ[myAtom[1, 2, 3]]` returns `True`. I'll write a full question about this.

Comment: @rcollyer: Apparently, the criteria is not `AtomQ` but `Length[exp]==0`. See Anon's comment in [this follow-up  question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/37057/8803).

Comment: Interesting. I'll have to play with it at some point.

Answer (score 10):

I like to think about @@ as a Frankstein decapitation operator. It take out the Head of the old expression and replace by the new one. And @@@ as a mass Frankstein decapitation operator. It get inside each list element and apply @@ to each element inside the list.

To understand what `Head` means, use `FullForm`. For example, in the list `l={1,2,3}` if you apply `FullForm@l`you get `List[1,2,3]`, where `List` is the `Head` of the expression.
If you want to sum the list, you can use `Plus@@l`, so you change `List[1,2,3]` by `Plus[1,2,3]`. List was decapted and replaced by `Plus`.

If you have `l={{1,2},{2,3}}` (that is equivalent to `List[List[1,2],List[2,3]]`), if you use Plus@@@l, you get `{3,5}`. `Plus` get into the list, and execute @@ in each element.

Comment: [@@ decapitation](http://reference.wolfram.com/legacy/flash/animations/Apply.html)

Answer (score 2):

You may think of it as follows: `@` applies a single-parameter function to a single argument, and `@@` applies a multi-parameter function to a list of arguments (effectively, replacing its head `List` with the function). And, as a bonus, `@@` works not only on lists with the `List` head, it can replace any head of a structured expression (but not heads of atomic expressions like numbers).

Comment: This description hides the fundamental feature of `Apply` that it replaces one head with another. Technically, a multi-parameter function is applied to a `Sequence` of arguments, not a `List` (or any other head there was around them, which gets "eaten up" by `Apply`).

Comment: @Vladimir Thanks for your reply. However, if I input Permutations@{x,y}, I have {{x,y},{y,x}}. It seems @ also apply to a set of argument.

Comment: @hongchaniyi It's just that some functions accept a signle argument that is itself a list.

Comment: @hongchaniyi: It might help if you visualize the `{}` as having an explicit head: `Permutations@{x,y} = Permutations@List[x,y] = Permutations[List[x,y]]`