# Decapitating "explicit" and "implicit" heads

Tags: functions, syntax

This is a follow up to [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/37040/8803).

So far, I named "explicit" heads to those that appear explicitly in the expression. For example, `f[x]` has an explicit head. I called "implicit" heads to those that are returned by `Head` but do not appear in the expression. For example, `5` has `Integer` as implicit head.

In the comments of the original question, rcollyer pointed out that the head of `Complex[1,2]` is explicit but `f@@Complex[1,2]` is not "decapitated" because `AtomQ@Complex[1, 2]` returns `True`. Then, I came up with the following code:

```
myAtom /: AtomQ[myAtom[__]] := True
f @@ myAtom[1, 2, 3]
(*f[1,2,3]*)
```

*How does `Apply` know when the head can be replaced?*

According to the documentation of [Apply](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Apply.html?q=Apply&lang=en):

> Applying to atomic objects that do not have subparts effectively does nothing

Thus, it seems that checking with `AtomQ` is not enough. One should also check for the existence of parts. For example, `Complex[1,2][[1]]` returns an error but `myAtom[1, 2, 3][[1]]` does not. Incidentally, `TreeForm[Complex[1, 2]]` shows "parts".

Hence the question: **Is there a function that makes both checks at once?**

---

Follow up:

**Is there any way to make a head non-decapitable?**

Is there a statement similar to `myAtom /: AtomQ[myAtom[__]] := True` such that

```
Map[f, {1, {2, myAtom[3]}}, {-1}]
```

will return `{f[1], {f[2], f[myAtom[3]]}}`?

Comment: `Length[expr]==0` is the test you're looking for, I think, but someone else would have to confirm that it always works. I don't know that much about this. I guessed it because it checks the criteria that you quoted and works for `Complex`.

Comment: @Anon: `Length[{}]==0` yet `f@@{}==f[]`. The original question seems now just a convoluted way towards `Length[#] == 0 && AtomQ[#] &`.

Comment: It is also true that `Length@f[] == 0`. :/ I don't think it's possible to create a fake atom. I hope someone proves me wrong.