# how do I can create a list of the first interval such as [-10+Sin [k], 10+Sin [K]]

Tags: intervals

A (k) =the closed interval [-10+Sin [k], 10+Sin [k]]
How do I can create a list of the first 20 of such interval
The find the intersection of the first 14 of them

Comment: Is k integer? Use Range and IntervalIntersetcion[]

Comment: Yes k is an integer number

Answer (score 2):

The code

```
ak = N[Table[Interval[{-10 + Sin[k], 10 + Sin[k]}], {k, 1, 20}]];
```

computes the first 20 as intervals. Remove the `N[ ]` wrapper for the exact values. You can then compute the intersection of the first 14 as closed intervals with

```
IntervalIntersection @@ ak[[1;;14]]
```

Finally this is the correct intersection: `Interval[{-9.00939, 9.00001}]`

Comment: What's @ means? ?

Comment: @Nana `@@` -`Apply`. [Difference between @ and @@.](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/37040/5478)

Comment: .. thank you :-)

Comment: I see the problem 1 sec

Comment: I'm really confuse now... what is the corect code in this case?

Comment: {-9.15853, 10.8415}

Comment: Just wait while I fix this

Comment: Sorry about that. You're good to go.

Answer (score 2):

```
c = IntervalIntersection @@ (Array[ Interval[{-10 + Sin[#], 10 + Sin[#]}] &, {20}][[;; 14]])

Graphics[{Array[Line[{{-10 + Sin[#], #}, {10 + Sin[#], #}}] &, {14}], 
         Red, c /. Interval[{x_, y_}] -> Line@{{x, 0}, {y, 0}}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 1):

We can use properties of `Interval` earlier:

```
f = Sin[#] + Interval[{-10, 10}]&;
IntervalIntersection @@ Array[f, 14] // N
```

> ```
> Interval[{-9.00939, 9.00001}]
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You can answer this question without knowing anything about interval functions: the intersection of all the intervals is the interval between (10-largest value of Sin) and (10+smallest value of Sin). With Sin assuming integer values between 1 and 14, this is:

```
{10 - Max[Sin[Range[14]]], 10 + Min[Sin[Range[14]]]}
{10 - Sin[14], 10 + Sin[11]}//N
{9.00939, 9.00001}
```