# Trouble understanding a piece of code found on Wolfram Blog

Tags: list-manipulation

I am trying to go through this Wolfram Blog example: http://blog.wolfram.com/2009/02/12/flag-analysis-with-mathematica/ on country flag analysis.

I am having a problem understanding the following piece of code:

```
countryColors =
  (# -> Catch[Intersection[
          StringSplit[
           If[Head[#] === Missing, Throw[""], #]& @
            CountryData[#, "FlagDescription"]],
          colorNames]]) & /@ CountryData[];
```

where `colorNames` is just a list of colors.

I do not understand `&@` in the above piece of code. What I know is that `&` is used to define a pure function, and `@` is used as a Prefix.

If, for example, the `If` yields true, then it returns a country name. What does it mean to have `&@` after that?

Comment: `f[#]&@a` works like `f[a]`. Here `a` is `CountryData[...`.

Comment: The question is well posed, but the solution is easily found, so I am voting to close.

Comment: @YvesKlett - you give an answer and then vote to close? hmm

Comment: @eldo the intension was to help the OP, regardless of (potential) closure. Related: http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1101. Now that three answers have appeared, others might vote for leaving open in any case.

Comment: @YvesKlett - yes, probably one should close this, because the code gives utterly wrong answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already had all blocks in place. `&` denotes a pure function, and `@` is used for prefix notation. As stated by @Kuba, `f[#]&@x` is basically equivalent to f[x].

Some subtleties on pre- and postfix are discussed e.g. [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/30425/131) and [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/19219/131).

One reason for using (or ending up using) this syntax may be that you can easily switcht to a list of arguments together with `Map` (e.g. `f[#]&/@{x1,x2,x3}`).

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps it will be easier to understand if I rewrite rgthe blog code in a more step-by-step but less efficient way.

```
colorNames = {"red", "white", "blue", "green", "yellow", "black"};
flagColors[countryName_] :=
  Module[{description},
    description = CountryData[countryName, "FlagDescription"];
    If[Head[description] === Missing,
      {""},
      Intersection[StringSplit[description], colorNames]]]
countryColors =
  Module[{countryNames, colors},
   countryNames = CountryData[];
   colors = flagColors /@ countryNames;
   MapThread[Rule, {countryNames, colors}]]
```

> ```
> {"Afghanistan" -> {"black", "red", "white"}, 
>  "Albania" -> {"black", "red"}, 
>  "Algeria" -> {"green", "red"}, 
>  "AmericanSamoa" -> {"red", "white"},
>  ...
>  "WesternSahara" -> {""}, 
>  "Yemen" -> {"green", "red", "white"}, 
>  "Zambia" -> {"green", "red"}, 
>  "Zimbabwe" -> {"black", "green", "red", "white", "yellow"}}
> ```

There is a bug in the above code because

```
flagColors["UnitedStates"]
```

> ```
> {"blue", "red"}
> ```

This is caused by the `Intersection` expression rejecting "white," and "white;" -- the only instances where white shows up in the flag description. This flaw is also found in the blog code.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you have to precede the code example with

```
colorNames = ToLowerCase[First /@ ColorData["Legacy", "ColorRules"]];
```

to make it understandable and executable.

You can then define:

```
FlagColors[x_] := x -> (Intersection[StringSplit["" /@ CountryData[x, "FlagDescription"]], 
   colorNames]) // Quiet
```

to obtain with

```
FlagColors /@ CountryData[]
```

the desired result

I find the author's code rather obscure. Instead of defining a separate function like `FlagColors` he plugged it with `&@` as a pure function into his code making it nearly unreadable.

Aside from this, the author produces wrong answers (f.e., the flag of Bulgaria is not white but white-green-red).